# Splitting a string at every n-th character

Tags: java, regex, string, split

In JavaScript this is how we can split a string at every 3-rd character

```
"foobarspam".match(/.{1,3}/g)
```

I am trying to figure out how to do this in Java. Any pointers?

Comment: I wouldn't use Regex for this task.

Comment: ok. What would you suggest then?

Comment: Something like Simon's answer.

Comment: I second your recommendation.  No extra libraries to install, Simon's solution worked great.

Answer (score 153, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
String s = "1234567890";
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(s.split("(?<=\\G...)")));
```

which produces:

```
[123, 456, 789, 0]
```

The regex `(?<=\G...)` matches an empty string that has the **last match** (`\G`) followed by **three characters** (`...`) **before** it (`(?<= )`)

Comment: Brrr... scary :) Java's regex flavor is a bit alien to me.

Comment: :) I'd probably go for Simon's solution as well: my co-workers might not like it if I start adding my regex-trickery to the code base.

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely scary. Scary, but brilliant! +1.

Comment: I'd hate to think someone voted this answer down simply because they don't like regular expressions.

Comment: I would stick to your's and Kenny's advices and go with a non-regex solution. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem, and (probably) a wise decision.

Comment: mad props for supreme regex mojo, but as a reader of this code, I'd hunt you down and egg your house. :)

Comment: As long as you call this via a correctly named function (ie splitIntoParts) and don't directly embed that line in your code, it's all good. Otherwise, let the hunting begin :)

Comment: Part of what makes this trick so scary is that it won't work in all languages.  For example, JavaScript doesn't support `\G`, and Python won't split on a regex that matches zero characters.  But then, if Java had a "get all matches" method like every other language does, you wouldn't have had to invent this trick in the first place, @Bart. ;)

Comment: This regex looks more like the brainf**k language, but obviously it is great answer

Comment: I copy/pasted this into my Android Studio project and I get `[123, 4567890]` as result :(

Comment: @EvrenYurtesen no idea why that is, but here's an online demo that shows it works: https://repl.it/repls/TalkativeAmusingGlueware

Comment: @BartKiers Apparently android is broken and nobody can be bothered to report or fix it :) Maybe Oracle should sue Google for making incompatible Java. Here is somebody else having same problem without a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36030109/regex-for-string-splitting-not-working-properly

Comment: how can we split by dynamic number of characters instead of 3 in this case.

Comment: @rafa `s.split("(?<=\\G.{" + number + "})")`

Comment: I need a way to account for line terminators. Is that possible with the way that Java handles look-behinds? I attempted my own pattern, but it failed with the exception: `Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Look-behind group does not have an obvious maximum length near index 14
(?<=\G(.|$){10})`

Comment: @CardinalSystem the $ does not match a line break, it matches the end of the input string, or the end of a line (not the line break itself!). Try this: `(?<=\G[\s\S]{10})`. The `[\s\S]` matches any character, so also line breaks.

Answer (score 93):

Java does not provide very full-featured splitting utilities, so the [Guava libraries](https://github.com/google/guava) do:

```
Iterable<String> pieces = Splitter.fixedLength(3).split(string);
```

Check out the [Javadoc for Splitter](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html); it's very powerful.

Comment: +1 This is the correct answer (also known as: *know and use the libraries*)

Comment: I would take this answer over the regex...just because it's more maintainable (e.g. the fact that less people know about RegEx than ppl being able to read "readable" code.)

Comment: only good if you already have Guava dependency. Otherwise, you need to add another dependency - something you should not do without checking with coworkers/system architect first.

Comment: Adding a full library so you can just use one method is not the best practice in most cases, also adding a library is always a big decision in an enterprise environment.

Answer (score 57):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (String part : getParts("foobarspam", 3)) {
            System.out.println(part);
        }
    }
    private static List<String> getParts(String string, int partitionSize) {
        List<String> parts = new ArrayList<String>();
        int len = string.length();
        for (int i=0; i<len; i+=partitionSize)
        {
            parts.add(string.substring(i, Math.min(len, i + partitionSize)));
        }
        return parts;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you keep a collection of substrings that cover the entire original string, the new String method will actually waste (n-1)*sizeof(int). The new Strings' char arrays will take the same memory, but each one will have a separate length field. That said, if any substrings are later discarded, new String could reduce memory. I wouldn't worry either way unless the original string is very big.

Comment: @DenisTulskiy could you elaborate? The `substring` method is actually smart enough to use the parent string's `char[]` for the data; see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2163570/732016) for more details.

Comment: @WChargin: hmm, you're right, I have no idea why I wrote that comment. I'll delete it. Thanks.

Comment: I would say this answer as correct as the regex one only separates once.

Answer (score 12):

As an addition to [Bart Kiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297347/splitting-a-string-at-every-n-th-character/2297450#2297450) answer I want to add that it is possible instead of using the three dots `...` in the regex expression which are representing three characters you can write `.{3}` which has the same meaning.

Then the code would look like the following:

```
String bitstream = "00101010001001010100101010100101010101001010100001010101010010101";
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(bitstream.split("(?<=\\G.{3})")));
```

With this it would be easier to modify the string length and the creation of a function is now reasonable with a variable input string length. This could be done look like the following:

```
public static String[] splitAfterNChars(String input, int splitLen){
    return input.split(String.format("(?<=\\G.{%1$d})", splitLen));
}
```

An example in IdeOne: http://ideone.com/rNlTj5

Comment: it is better solution, could you please tell about Regex format?

Comment: As I used the same solution that was already explained from Bart Kiers, I can refer to his answer. The `%1$d` will be replaced with the decimal value of the variable `splitLen`.
Otherwise [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) could be also very helpful for you.

Answer (score 4):

Late Entry.

Following is a succinct implementation using Java8 streams, a one liner:

```
String foobarspam = "foobarspam";
AtomicInteger splitCounter = new AtomicInteger(0);
Collection<String> splittedStrings = foobarspam
                                    .chars()
                                    .mapToObj(_char -> String.valueOf((char)_char))
                                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(stringChar -> splitCounter.getAndIncrement() / 3
                                                                ,Collectors.joining()))
                                    .values();
```

Output:

```
[foo, bar, spa, m]
```

Comment: "a one liner" ;)

Answer (score 1):

This a late answer, but I am putting it out there anyway for any new programmers to see:

If  you do  not want to use regular expressions, *and* do not wish to  rely on a third party library, you can use this method instead, which takes between 
 **89920** and **100113** nanoseconds in a **2.80 GHz CPU** (less than a millisecond). It's not as pretty as Simon Nickerson's example, but it works:

```
   /**
     * Divides the given string into substrings each consisting of the provided
     * length(s).
     * 
     * @param string
     *            the string to split.
     * @param defaultLength
     *            the default length used for any extra substrings. If set to
     *            <code>0</code>, the last substring will start at the sum of
     *            <code>lengths</code> and end at the end of <code>string</code>.
     * @param lengths
     *            the lengths of each substring in order. If any substring is not
     *            provided a length, it will use <code>defaultLength</code>.
     * @return the array of strings computed by splitting this string into the given
     *         substring lengths.
     */
    public static String[] divideString(String string, int defaultLength, int... lengths) {
        java.util.ArrayList<String> parts = new java.util.ArrayList<String>();

        if (lengths.length == 0) {
            parts.add(string.substring(0, defaultLength));
            string = string.substring(defaultLength);
            while (string.length() > 0) {
                if (string.length() < defaultLength) {
                    parts.add(string);
                    break;
                }
                parts.add(string.substring(0, defaultLength));
                string = string.substring(defaultLength);
            }
        } else {
            for (int i = 0, temp; i < lengths.length; i++) {
                temp = lengths[i];
                if (string.length() < temp) {
                    parts.add(string);
                    break;
                }
                parts.add(string.substring(0, temp));
                string = string.substring(temp);
            }
            while (string.length() > 0) {
                if (string.length() < defaultLength || defaultLength <= 0) {
                    parts.add(string);
                    break;
                }
                parts.add(string.substring(0, defaultLength));
                string = string.substring(defaultLength);
            }
        }

        return parts.toArray(new String[parts.size()]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using plain java:

```java
    String s = "1234567890";
    List<String> list = new Scanner(s).findAll("...").map(MatchResult::group).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.printf("%s%n", list);
```

Produces the output:

> [123, 456, 789]

Note that this discards leftover characters (0 in this case).

Answer (score 0):

You can also split a string at every n-th character and put them each, in each index of a List :

Here I made a list of Strings named Sequence :

> List < String > Sequence

Then I'm basically splitting the String "KILOSO" by every 2 words. So 'KI' 'LO' 'SO' would be incorporate in separate index of the List called Sequence.

> String S = KILOSO
>
> > Sequence = Arrays.asList(S.split("(?<=\G..)"));

So when I'm doing :

> System.out.print(Sequence)

It should print :

> [KI, LO, SO]

to verify I can write :

> System.out.print(Sequence.get(1))

it will print :

> LO

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered this issue, and here is the solution I came up with

```
final int LENGTH = 10;
String test = "Here is a very long description, it is going to be past 10";

Map<Integer,StringBuilder> stringBuilderMap = new HashMap<>();
for ( int i = 0; i < test.length(); i++ ) {
    int position = i / LENGTH; // i<10 then 0, 10<=i<19 then 1, 20<=i<30 then 2, etc.

    StringBuilder currentSb = stringBuilderMap.computeIfAbsent( position, pos -> new StringBuilder() ); // find sb, or create one if not present
    currentSb.append( test.charAt( i ) ); // add the current char to our sb
}

List<String> comments = stringBuilderMap.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted( Comparator.comparing( Map.Entry::getKey ) )
        .map( entrySet -> entrySet.getValue().toString() )
        .collect( Collectors.toList() );
//done



// here you can see the data
comments.forEach( cmt -> System.out.println( String.format( "'%s' ... length= %d", cmt, cmt.length() ) ) );
// PRINTS:
// 'Here is a ' ... length= 10
// 'very long ' ... length= 10
// 'descriptio' ... length= 10
// 'n, it is g' ... length= 10
// 'oing to be' ... length= 10
// ' past 10' ... length= 8

// make sure they are equal
String joinedString = String.join( "", comments );
System.out.println( "\nOriginal strings are equal " + joinedString.equals( test ) );
// PRINTS: Original strings are equal true
```