# Convert a String of Hex into ASCII in Java

Tags: java, string, ascii, hex

I hope this isn't too much of a stupid question, I have looked on 5 different pages of Google results but haven't been able to find anything on this.

What I need to do is convert a string that contains all Hex characters into ASCII for example

```
String fileName = 

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
```

Every way I have seen makes it seems like you have to put it into an array first. Is there no way to loop through each two and convert them?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Just use a for loop to go through each couple of characters in the string, convert them to a character and then whack the character on the end of a string builder:

```
String hex = "75546f7272656e745c436f6d706c657465645c6e667375635f6f73745f62795f6d757374616e675c50656e64756c756d2d392c303030204d696c65732e6d7033006d7033006d7033004472756d202620426173730050656e64756c756d00496e2053696c69636f00496e2053696c69636f2a3b2a0050656e64756c756d0050656e64756c756d496e2053696c69636f303038004472756d2026204261737350656e64756c756d496e2053696c69636f30303800392c303030204d696c6573203c4d757374616e673e50656e64756c756d496e2053696c69636f3030380050656e64756c756d50656e64756c756d496e2053696c69636f303038004d50330000";
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < hex.length(); i+=2) {
    String str = hex.substring(i, i+2);
    output.append((char)Integer.parseInt(str, 16));
}
System.out.println(output);
```

Or (Java 8+) if you're feeling particularly uncouth, use the infamous "fixed width string split" hack to enable you to do a one-liner with streams instead:

```
System.out.println(Arrays
        .stream(hex.split("(?<=\\G..)")) //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297347/splitting-a-string-at-every-n-th-character
        .map(s -> Character.toString((char)Integer.parseInt(s, 16)))
        .collect(Collectors.joining()));
```

Either way, this gives a few lines starting with the following:

> uTorrent\Completed\nfsuc_ost_by_mustang\Pendulum-9,000 Miles.mp3

Hmmm... :-)

Comment: This question wins the award of "Most Self-Incriminating Question of the Year".

Comment: Ha ha good point, but lucky for me this file is from a once live case so I'm in the clear but I didn't think ha ha! Made me laugh though :)

Comment: Thank you "berry120" that has helped me loads! :)

Comment: Given that the size of the string is known in advance, one might optimise the `StringBuilder` to hold it all or even use just a `char[]`. Only relevant if this will be run often, of course.

Comment: I know this is an old question but just for info Guava 14 introduced a [BaseEncoding](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/BaseEncoding.html) class which would be used like `new String(BaseEncoding.base16().lowerCase().decode(hex), Charsets.US_ASCII)` - the BaseEncoding instance can be cached as it's immutable

Answer (score 13):

Easiest way to do it with `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter`:

```
    String hex = "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";
    byte[] s = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(hex);
    System.out.println(new String(s));
```

Comment: This solution gives the same results as the accepted answer.

Comment: in my case the string started with 0x and I got an exception that complained about illegal characters (the x in this case) so I just had to do a substring(2) to exclude those.  ^_^

Comment: I had different outputs, I dont know what went wrong. 
String : B54075546f7272656e745c436f6d706c657465645c6e667375635f6f73745f62795f6d757374616e675c50656e64756c75
with out DatatypeConverter : 
µ@uTorrent\Completed\nfsuc_ost_by_mustang\Pendulu
with DatatypeConverter : �@uTorrent\Completed\nfsuc_ost_by_mustang\Pendulu

Answer (score 3):

```
String hexToAscii(String s) {
  int n = s.length();
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(n / 2);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i += 2) {
    char a = s.charAt(i);
    char b = s.charAt(i + 1);
    sb.append((char) ((hexToInt(a) << 4) | hexToInt(b)));
  }
  return sb.toString();
}

private static int hexToInt(char ch) {
  if ('a' <= ch && ch <= 'f') { return ch - 'a' + 10; }
  if ('A' <= ch && ch <= 'F') { return ch - 'A' + 10; }
  if ('0' <= ch && ch <= '9') { return ch - '0'; }
  throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.valueOf(ch));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Convert a string representation of a hex dump to a byte array using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140131/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-hex-dump-to-a-byte-array-using-java)

Disregarding encoding, etc. you can do `new String (hexStringToByteArray("75546..."));`

Answer (score 2):

So as I understand it, you need to pull out successive pairs of hex digits, then decode that 2-digit hex number and take the corresponding char:

```
String s = "...";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s.length() / 2);
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i+=2) {
    String hex = "" + s.charAt(i) + s.charAt(i+1);
    int ival = Integer.parseInt(hex, 16);
    sb.append((char) ival);
}
String string = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% HEX to ASCII %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
public String convertHexToString(String hex){

 String ascii="";
 String str;

 // Convert hex string to "even" length
 int rmd,length;
 length=hex.length();
 rmd =length % 2;
 if(rmd==1)
 hex = "0"+hex;

  // split into two characters
  for( int i=0; i<hex.length()-1; i+=2 ){

      //split the hex into pairs
      String pair = hex.substring(i, (i + 2));
      //convert hex to decimal
      int dec = Integer.parseInt(pair, 16);
      str=CheckCode(dec);
      ascii=ascii+" "+str;
  }
  return ascii;
}

public String CheckCode(int dec){
  String str;

          //convert the decimal to character
        str = Character.toString((char) dec);

      if(dec<32 || dec>126 && dec<161)
             str="n/a";  
  return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To this case, I have a hexadecimal data format into an int array and I want to convert them on String.

```
int[] encodeHex = new int[] { 0x48, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6f }; // Hello encode
for (int i = 0; i < encodeHex.length; i++) {
   System.out.print((char) (encodeHex[i]));
}
```