# How to convert a hex integer to string

Tags: java

I have an API that sends data back & forth between client and server. On the client side there is a parser that takes this data and puts it into a properties file.

I have converted the string data on the server side to a hex integer to avoid getting in trouble with my parser because I split my data on characters like ";" and "_". So if my data contains any of those characters it will cause problems with my parser.

```
server send: SC;4b6579_56616c7565;4b65790a4e65776c696e65_56616c75650a4e65776c696e65;4b65795f556e64657273636f7265_56616c75655f556e64657273636f7265
client received: SC;4b6579_56616c7565;4b65790a4e65776c696e65_56616c75650a4e65776c696e65;4b65795f556e64657273636f7265_56616c75655f556e64657273636f7265
```

So some sample data would be

```
String key = "4b6579";
String value = "56616c7565";

int hexKey = Integer.parseInt(key, 16);
int hexValue = Integer.parseInt(value, 16);
```

How do I turn my `hexKey` and `hexValue` into strings?

The result should be as below:

- `4b6579` converts to the word `Key`
- `56616c7565` converts to the word `Value`

EDIT:

The answer was found here: [Convert a String of Hex into ASCII in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785654/convert-a-string-of-hex-into-ascii-in-java)

Comment: Usually it's better to use something commonly used instead of custom implementation. E.g. you can use JSON serialized to BASE64 for eliminate (de)serialization and different encodings problem. Also could you provide you server code which converts server data to content you are sending.

Comment: So you're trying to convert the specific value "4b6579" to the specific string "key"?  In that case, you should just map the value to a string.  You could use a simple switch statement.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc this is a duplicate of your link, thank you. That should fix my problem.

Comment: The answer can be found in the solution of this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785654/convert-a-string-of-hex-into-ascii-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's something that could help:

```
String hex = "2A"; //The answer is 42  
int intValue = Integer.parseInt(hex, 16);

//this is the line you want
String hex = Integer.toHexString(42);//pass in int here
```

Also, you could easily use hex numbers in Java instead of Strings.

```
int[] x = {0xA4, 0x21};
```

EDIT:  If the original question meant to ask how to convert hex into ASCII, then I'd recommend checking out the following:

[Convert a String of Hex into ASCII in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785654/convert-a-string-of-hex-into-ascii-in-java)

Sources:

http://www.codebeach.com/2008/02/convert-hex-string-to-integer-and-back.html

Comment: This is the same as the others. It returns KEY: 4b6579 instead of KEY: key

Comment: Check out my edit.  I believe that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes it is. I have already added the answer to the question though but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to turn the `hexKey` and `hexValue` to `String`, just do this.

```
String.valueOf(hexKey);
String.valueOf(hexValue);
```

Instead of `Integer.parseInt(key, 16)`, use `Long.parseLong(key, 16);`

Comment: for hexKey this gives me 4941177 which is not the correct value and for hexValue it throws a NumberFormatException. So this doesn't work.

Comment: Well, your `Integer.parseInt` throws an exception.

Comment: The fact remains that String.valueOf(hexKey) does not convert my hexKey to the word Key but to 4941177

Comment: @JorisRenting Your question is not clear. Could you tell us what Strings you want to get from `hexKey` and `hexValue`?

Comment: @Pshemo I wrote it in the question... 4b6579 converts to the word key
56616c7565 converts to the word value

Comment: And how should java know that this particular numbers has to become word "key". Then you asked your question wrong. The question is" "how to map certain numbers to certain words?" The answer is: "use a map".

Comment: 4b6579 is hex code for the word "key". Try running it through a hex to string converter: http://www.string-functions.com/hex-string.aspx

Comment: @JorisRenting Are you sure? Even if what you are asking is converting hex to ASCII (which is not obvious from your question) then it would be `Key` and `Value`.

Comment: @JorisRenting then your answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785654/convert-a-string-of-hex-into-ascii-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

```
String hex = Integer.toHexString(hexKey);
```

http://www.codebeach.com/2008/02/convert-hex-string-to-integer-and-back.html

Comment: this returns KEY: 4b6579 for me, which is just the contents of hexKey converted from int to String. So this doesn't work.

Comment: I was just answering the question: "How to convert a hex integer to string"  There is no hex integer, there's just an integer represented in hex format.

Comment: But my question is how do I convert the hex value to a string? I think the question was elaborated quite clearly.

Comment: 4b6579 converts to the string "key", simply mapping it with a switch statement doesn't do me any good because I need to be able to convert any hex code to a string

Comment: And I answered your elaborated question.  It was you who failed to state what kind of string.  You simply said string.  If you had asked how to convert hex into ASCII, then darijan, Mohammad and I wouldn't have been confused.  However, I'm not going to mark the question down, that wouldn't be nice.

Comment: If I knew that I had to look for hex into ASCII I would have found the answer to my question without having to create this one. Pshemo and Gillbert Le Blanc were able to figure out and help me with my problem. I didn't fail at anything because my question was answered and I can continue with my work now. But it wasn't you who was able to help me ;)