# Convert Hex to Decimal and Decimal to TimeStamp in JAVA

Tags: java

I have facing Problem in Parsing 16 digit hex string to decimal integer value.

I have tried following code for converting hex to decimal:

```
    String HexString= "0000113fc208dff"; 
    int dec= Long.parseLong(HexString);
```

But its throwing `NumberFormatException: Invalid int ...`

Now How do i Convert to Decimal/Binary  and Further Convert  Decimal/Binary to Time Stamp ??

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's still an `int` (or in this case, `long`).  Try parsing it as a `long` and see what you turn up with.

Comment: We have tried with long also its showing same exeption

Comment: What you looking for is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785654/convert-a-string-of-hex-into-ascii-in-java

Comment: We dont want it in ascii we are trying to parse in decimal only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first parameter is the String, second parameter is the radix

```
long epoch=Long.parseLong(str, 16);
```

Then convert to Timestamp through Calendar

```
Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTimeInMillis(epoch);
```

Answer (score 2):

try this code

```
String HexString= "0000113fc208dff"; 
long dec= Long.parseLong(HexString, 16);
System.out.println(dec);
```

Result:

```
1185345998335
```