# Android - ASCII and HEX Value

Tags: android, string, hex, ascii

If this is a duplicate, first of all, I'm sorry I've been looking all around and I haven't found how to solve my problem (or my head is too messed up).

I think that is better if I throw my problem rather than explain it.

I have an integer value wich is **int**`234`. I convert this value to its **hex string** representation `EA`. Note that this is `"EA"`, it is a string.

Then I use `Integer.parseInt` to convert it to `0xEA` (which is an hex value, not hex string) and finally I need the ASCII (or character) representation of this value.

The problem is that when I decode it using `Integer.toHexString` I get `C3AA` instead of `EA`

[This](https://www.google.com.ar/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=10&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CFMQFjAJahUKEwiRi8nV6qTHAhWCTJAKHa6uAHg&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F7861803%2Futf-8-strings-in-a-mysql-database-got-messed-up-after-configuration-change&ei=6ejLVdHyE4KZwQSu3YLABw&usg=AFQjCNGJsVyLLsQqrUuh5OHb1kkUMYYzTw&sig2=a-k1LCVBtz0o0_9LKi4rhA&bvm=bv.99804247,d.Y2I) is the best explanation I've found. But still I don't know how to solve it..

I hope you can help me out! Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

I'd like to transmit the int `234` in a UDP datagram that's why I use the conversions. (This UDP channel mainly sends ASCII ("234") but I want an exception to that and once in a while transmit it in ony 1byte) That's why I do all this conversions (maybe it is easier than this, but I think I'm too close the problem that I can't see it with clarity)

I can confortly do it in `C` but I need to do it in `Java`. And my head is going crazy.

So `234` toHexString becomes `hex="EA";

```
// HEX -> ASCII code
    for(int i=0; i<hex.length()-1; i+=2 ){
        String output = hex.substring(i, (i + 2));
        int decimal = Integer.parseInt(output, 16);
        result.append((char)decimal);   
    }
    return result.toString();
```

As result I get a strange character (the one that @fadden said). Now a question: this value is 2bytes long?

I transmit this odd character and when I use `str = Integer.toHexString(prevResult);` I get C3AA.

Maybe I'm messing thing up, but what I want is just to transmit 0xEA(byte) and get the int `234` in the other side.

For Example, Let's say I'd like to transmit the word "COMMAND" and append the value 234. Normally I would send "COMMAND234" but now I need the command value to be only one byte long. So the hex representation of what I'd be transmitting would be:

`0x67 0x79 0x77 0x77 0x65 0x78 0x68 0xEA
 C    O    M    M    A    N    D    234`

Comment: Why not leave hex like string and use this code? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785654/convert-a-string-of-hex-into-ascii-in-java

Comment: I think your linked answer has it exactly: "The ê character is EA, in UTF-8, that would be C3 AA." There is no ASCII encoding for ê. You're getting the UTF-8 encoding. Are you attempting to create a CP-1252 character (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)?

Comment: Thank you both for your replies. @Santiago I'm using that code, see my edited question. fadden: I don't really undestand what you said, please also look my edited question