# SOAP asciihex encoding

Tags: soap, encoding, soapui, soap-client

I would really appreciate if anyone can help me with this, I looked a bit into this issue on the internet but no results.

As a client, I'm retrieving a SOAP message trough a GET request, the message is encoded trough "asciihex" encoding.

The documentation says this - "If the file is downloaded, it will be encoded and the client has to decode it to read it correctly. Currently, CCon supports just asciihex encoding mode. If this mode is used, every single original byte is encoded as a sequence of two characters representing it in hexadecimal. So, if the original byte was 0x0a, the transmitted bytes are 0x30 and 0x41 (‘0’ and ‘a’ in ASCII)."

Problem comes with encoding this message, I don't have any idea how to translate this into an intelligible text.
The messaging protocol used for this is SOAP, I'm testing this using SoapUI.

Comment: Create a Groovy step with this https://stackoverflow.com/q/4785654/3124333

Comment: Unfortunately this doens't work, only converts hex to ascii