# Java - separate number into 3 parts

Tags: java, int

Let's say I have following number:

```
36702514
```

I want to separate the above number into 3 parts, which is 36, 702, 514. 
Below is the code that I tried:

```
int num = 36702514;
int num1 = num.substring(0, 2);
int num2 = num.substring(2, 3);
int num3 = num.substring(5, 3);
```

Am I writing correct?

Comment: modulo 1000 or 100 would be the easiest way.

Comment: Lets say if you would have tried something before asking?

Comment: @KKLMichael Are we talking about this specific example or any number split into any number of permutation combinations? If you mean the later, one quick way to do it would be to use `String` manipulation.

Comment: It depends on what the data type is. If its a string look up using the string split operation if its an int you could use the % operator to separate it.

Comment: search can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495712/how-to-split-numbers-in-java

Comment: @KKLMichael Did you just copy paste someones answer into your question and claim that you tried it? This is absurd :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
List<String>  myNumbers = Arrays.asList(
    NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format(36702514).split(","));
```

My solution builds a comma-separated `String` of the input in US locale:

```
36,702,514
```

This `String` is then split by the comma to give the desired three pieces in the original problem.

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
Integer n = null;
for (String numb : myNumbers)
{
    try
    {
        n = new Integer(numb);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Wrong number " + numb);
        continue;
    }
    numbers.add(n);
}
System.out.println(numbers);
```

Comment: I voted up your answer because it is clean and concise.  The only thing I don't like is that you end up with a collection of strings which potentially have to be converted to numeric.

Comment: I also voted up because this is a method you can use if String is workable for you. I would urge you to flesh it out a little and explain how it works so the people using it can understand what it does.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `substring()` on a Java `String`, not a primitive `int`.  Convert your number to a `String` using `String.valueOf()`:

```
int num = 36702514;
String numString = String.valueOf(num);

int num1 = Integer.parseInt(numString.substring(0, 2));
int num2 = Integer.parseInt(numString.substring(2, 5));
int num3 = Integer.parseInt(numString.substring(5, 8));
```

Comment: Is `substring()` returns `int` value

Comment: but `substring()` return `String`

Comment: You'll be getting : `error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int` p.s. : (Not the Downvoter)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the modulus logic to extract the digits from an integer.

```
int num1 = num % 10;
int num2 = num / 10 % 10;
int num3 = num /100 % 10;

System.out.print(num1);
System.out.print("\n" + num2);
System.out.print("\n" + num3);
```

Edit : Store the digits in an array instead of seperate variables.

Answer (score -3):

> Am I writing correct?

No you aren't , you'll be getting compile time error as

```
error: int cannot be dereferenced
```

`num` is a primitive here , You can not call a method on primitive .

Correct way is :

```
int no = 36702514;
String num=String.valueOf(num);
int num1 = Integer.parseInt(num.substring(0, 2));
int num2 = Integer.parseInt(num.substring(2, 3));
int num3 = Integer.parseInt(num.substring(5, 3));
```