# How can I split words based on length using Java?

Tags: java

What is the best way to take a word and split it up between 2 to 4 character in length?

Examples:

- "tundra" could be "tun" & "dra" or "tund" & "ra"
- "rainforest" could be "ra" & "in" "fore" & "st"

Is there a method designed specifically to accomplish this?

Comment: Whats the pattern you are looking for exactly? Why cant "rainforest" be "ra", "in", "fo", "re" and "st"?

Comment: It can be. I am given a word with a length range of 4 to 16 characters, I need to break that word down to subworsd in a range of 2 to 4 characters that make up the original word.

Comment: You mean you need to come up will all combinations of 2-4 sized subwords of the original word?

Comment: Yes, Given a list of 7 words that vary in length from 4 to 16 characters I need to return a list of 20 strings making up those words. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use modulo operation on string length? With the result you can easily split your string in some pieces.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12295711/split-a-string-at-every-nth-position) on how to split at string at every nth position. You then just need to iterate over n from 2 to 4 to get all your substrings.