# How to load a file have records in horizontal pattern using PIG

Tags: apache-pig

I have a text file with records in horizontal pattern, how to load this file into a relation using PIG Latin.

File has patient id and patient name.

Data in the file:
001 Rakesh 005 Samir   006 Daksh 010 Kapil 456 Sachin...etc

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any out of the box loaders that will load the data in your format. You have two options.

1. Write a custom `LoadFunc`
2. Modify your input files so that theres only one record per line. Then you'll be able to use `PigStorage`

Answer (score 1):

You should preprocess your data or you can load your file and create a UDF to split it.

If you want to preprocess your data, I would recommend to create a script in a convenient language like Ruby or Python to do the job.

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13673133/1067688) for Python

Or else, if you want to create a UDF, you can use Google Guava library to split the line and then create an output of a bug with tuples.

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12295789/1067688) for Google Guava example.

Of course you have to be careful as you might have scalability issues with those methods.