# How do I split a string, without spaces, into multiple words in java?

Tags: java, string, split

I have a `String` array

```
String student [] = {"BAT4M0ABBB4M0ABOH4M0CCHI4U0AENG4U0DMDM4U0B"}
```

I need to split this for every 7 characters.
It should look like this:

```
String student {
"BAT4M0A",
"BBB4M0A",
"BOH4M0C",
"CHI4U0A",
"ENG4U0D",
"MDM4U0B"
}
```

This is my code so far.

```
       for (int i=0; i<= data.length; i++)
        {
          student= data[i].split(","); //data is a file of 1000 lines that is being read
          if (student [2].equals(sN)) //student is a line in the each file that has been  split into 11 parts
        {
            String timetable[]= student[9].split("(?<=\\G.......)");
            System.out.println (timetable);
            break;
        }
```

Comment: Do you want your end result to be an array of strings?

Comment: Plz see a similar thread

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12295711/split-a-string-at-every-nth-position

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do

```
String[] array = student[0].split("(?<=\\G.{7})");
```

`\G` is a meta character that matches the last match so `(?<=\\G.{7})` matches an empty string followed by any 7 characters

- [IDEOne Demo](http://ideone.com/odY7vB)

Comment: Can you please add an explanation of the regex?

Comment: yeh I would like to see it too

Comment: I had to put up a different question because I forgot that this string already exists in an array.

Comment: Given that you only have [one element in the array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21081845/how-can-i-split-a-string-array-which-contains-no-spaces-into-multiple-words-in), there's no reason why this wont still work

Comment: So do I add student[9].split ... instead of str.split... ?

Comment: What is `student` exactly? You need to update the question. If the question is _significantly_ different then open a new question with your code and explain the issue :)

Comment: I'm sorry for not specifying, please see my updated question.

Comment: that's way better, see update. Also have tidied question formatting :)

Comment: It is giving me an error. :( Is there a way I can send you my program to see what's wrong?

Comment: No, `SO` is a Q&A site. we dont do consultations. Have a look at the demo added, it has everything you need and more ;)

Comment: I have entered my code. Please see the changes. Sorry again for not being specific. This is my first question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use guava [`Splitter`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html):

```
String str = "BAT4M0ABBB4M0ABOH4M0CCHI4U0AENG4U0DMDM4U0B"
Iterable<String> parts = Splitter.fixedLength(7).split(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

use string.substring(i,j);
i is the first character and j is the last character.
It's easy to create a loop that goes through the whole string