# How to add String value to Arraylist in android

Tags: java, android, string, arraylist

I am going to create a sample application for add values to an `ArrayList` of `String`  in android

My Input is

```
String Value="123456789012345678901234567890234567890";
```

added Ten value to Array list it like below output

Output -is Added to Array list:

```
[1234567890,1234567890,1234567890,1234567890]
```

Even I have used Value + `/n`, but is not proper way how change it so it yields the expected result?

Comment: Sorry, no idea what your question is about - I do not understand what you are trying to say. Please try super simple english sentences: subject, verb, object. Post the code you have written, and point out what different result you want to achieve.

Comment: If English is not your native language, you might also want to try explaining the problem to a colleague or friend who shares your native language but has better English skills, so they can help you write your question clearly.

Comment: Mr.jon Skeet i am accept your comment.. thank you

Comment: Mr.vladimair Markeev ооо !! вибачте я шукати не там, нормально його дублікат питання !! що буде робити, я дати кращі ідеї смоктати хуй Ваш сам ..

Comment: Тайські Олі Mavane .. Mr.vladimair markeev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question you want to split a string every n characters. Use the following.

```
Arrays.toString(Value.split("(?<=\\G.{" + 10 + "})"))
```

For more info read this post [Split a string, at every nth position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12295711/split-a-string-at-every-nth-position)

Comment: Thanks i need this one ..