# Inserting a total characters per line in EditText

Tags: android, forms, sqlite, android-edittext, maxlength

i have an EditText in my InvoiceForm, that i wanna set per line a total of 40 characters, 
and when the user prompt these total, i need that automatically jumps, to the next line with a total of 40 also, and so on till 240 characters... or not necessary jumps to the next line, but store as another line with 40 characters at the total

And i need to save this text in my local database so i have the tables to my InvoiceForm tables with:

```
String createInvoice = "CREATE TABLE " 
            + TB_INVOICE
            + "(ID_INVOICE INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + "COD_INVOICE TEXT PRIMARY KEY,"
            + "DES_CLIENT TEXT, "
            + "COD_CLIENT TEXT, "
            + "NUM_SERIE TEXT, "
            + "TXT_DESCRIPTION TEXT );";  <--

String createTextForm = "CREATE TABLE " 
            + TB_TEXTINVOICE
            + "(ID_TXT_INVOICE INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " 
            + "COD_INVOICE TEXT PRIMARY KEY(SECONDARY KEY),"
            + " COD_LINE TEXT,"  <--
            + " LINE TEXT  );";  <--
```

So, here is my code and my UI, to make my description more clear[image]

And My Code:

```
    Button botao_salvar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_salvar);
    botao_salvar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            EditText Et_client = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchclient);
            EditText Et_nserie = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET_nserie);
            EditText Et_descrinota = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET_descrinota);

            if (Et_client.getText() == null || Et_nserie.getText() == null || Et_descrinota.getText() == null) {
                Toast.makeText(Formulario_Nota.this, "Voce não pode salvar um valor nulo, por favor insira dados nos campos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            } else if (Et_client.getText().length() < 2 || Et_nserie.getText().length() < 2 || Et_descrinota.getText().length() < 2) {
                Toast.makeText(Formulario_Nota.this, "Por favor insira dados completos. Sempre maior que 2 caracteres.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            } else {

                Nota notalist = nota_helper.pegaNotaDoFormulario();
                Stara_DB NotaDao = new Stara_DB(Formulario_Nota.this);

                notas = NotaDao.getListaNota();
                NotaDao.insereNota(notalist);

                Toast.makeText(Formulario_Nota.this, "Dados Salvos com sucesso", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                NotaDao.close();

                Intent continuar = new Intent(Formulario_Nota.this, Formulario_ItemNota.class);
                finish();
                startActivity(continuar);
                return;

            }
        }
    });
}
```

The user, dont needs to know about that, i will handle  this intern in my app

My question is, how can i perform this insert, like how can i recogonize, which line i need to store in My DB, because MyBackend only accepts per line a total of 40 characters in the description text field,

What i know for know is the property android:maxLength"40"; or something like that, but how can i perform this specific  insert  case each line in my DB, i already have the contentValues and everything else, i just wanna know the "logic" to do that, or examples... thanks a lot

Comment: Can you give a UI example of what you are trying to do? Do you only have one EditText view with multiple lines, or do you have multiple EditText views and you want to jump to the next EditText when 40 characters are reached? Anyway, you should have a look at TextWatchers.

Comment: i just update my post to let you guys know what i'm trying to do

Comment: hey @raveN i just updated my topic, i think knwo you will understand my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, I believe the user doesn't need to know that you have the 40 chars per field limit. You can just create 1 EditText for the description field, and restrict this single EditText to 240 chars total. Once you get the EditText value from the user after they click the submit button, you can write the logic by splitting the user input up to six 40 char strings, before inserting it into your DB.

Comment: hey @Marta i just updated my topic, i think knwo you will understand my problem

Comment: What you want to do is split your description string by each 40 chars into separate strings, name those strings descStr1 through descStr6 and then insert each of the 40 char descStrN values into each of the DB fields. The following link will give the logic of how to split your string by char length multiple ways: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276639/java-how-to-split-a-string-by-a-number-of-characters