# break large String into small Strings

Tags: java, string, android-studio

i have a large  string  which contains Id's example :

**HD47-4585-GG89**

here at the above  i have an id of a single object but sometimes it may contain id's of multiple objects  like this :

**HD47-4585-GG89-KO89-9089-RT45**

the above haves ids of 2 objects now i want to convert the above string to an array or in multiple small Strings 
something like :

**id1 =  HD47-4585-GG89**

**id2 = KO89-9089-RT45**

every single id haves a fixed number of characters in it here its 14 (counting the symbols too) and the number of total id's in a single String is not determined

i dont know how to do it any one can guide me with this ?

i think all i have to do is clip the first 14 characters of string then assign a variable to it and repeat this until string is empty

Comment: What's wrong with your method?

Comment: i'm not a java guy i have to do it for a server side code thats why i dont know where to start @JornVernee

Comment: i got this api `s = s.substring(0, Math.min(s.length(), 14));`  for trimming the first 14 characters but how to deal with this `-` symbol which is combining two id's

Comment: This will help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276639/java-how-to-split-a-string-by-a-number-of-characters

Comment: @remyboys You could skip 1 character after finding an id.

Comment: thanks guys for responding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use regex:

```
String input = "HD47-4585-GG89-KO89-9089-RT45";

Pattern id = Pattern.compile("(\\w{4}-\\w{4}-\\w{4})");
Matcher matcher = id.matcher(input);

List<String> ids = new ArrayList<>();

while(matcher.find()) {
    ids.add(matcher.group(1));
}

System.out.println(ids); // [HD47-4585-GG89, KO89-9089-RT45]
```

See [Ideone](http://ideone.com/SJHr7K).

Although this assumes that each group of characters (`HD47`) is 4 long.

Answer (score 1):

Using guava Splitter

```
class SplitIt
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String idString = "HD47-4585-GG89-KO89-9089-RT45-HD47-4585-GG89";

        Iterable<String> result = Splitter
                .fixedLength(15)
                .trimResults(CharMatcher.inRange('-', '-'))
                .split(idString);
        String[] parts = Iterables.toArray(result, String.class);
        for (String id : parts) {
            System.out.println(id);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(String,"-");

while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {

```
   System.out.println(st.nextToken());
```

}

these tokens can be stored in some arrays and then using index you can get required data.

Comment: [_"StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code."_](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)