# Split a string by fixed number of chars

Tags: string, split, kotlin

Is there a quick way to split a String by fixed number of chars in Kotlin?

I need to split this `544A1609B62E`, lowercase it, add `:` where needed and achieve this: `54:4a:16:09:b6:2e`.

What would be the idiomatic way to do it?

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/split.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Kotlin 1.2 you can do this:

```
"544A1609B62E".toLowerCase().chunked(2).joinToString(":")
```

The `chunked` function is new in Kotlin 1.2. It splits a collection into chunks of the given size.

Doing this in Kotlin 1.1 or lower is a bit more cumbersome. You could look at the answers in the question posted by @NSimon here: [Java: How to split a string by a number of characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276639/java-how-to-split-a-string-by-a-number-of-characters)

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I am looking for... in the future :) I ended up doing something like this: private fun formatMacAddress(): String {
        return id.toLowerCase()
                .mapIndexed { index, char ->
                    if (index != 0 && index % 2 == 0) ":$char" else "$char" }
                .joinToString("")
    } probably won't format in the comment, but you get the idea...

Comment: @lidkxx Nice, that looks actually pretty good! Btw, you can format code in comments by wrapping it in backticks ( ` )

Answer (score 2):

Another try in Kotlin,

```
val sampleString = "544A1609B62E"
        var i = 0
        var sampleBuffer = "";
        while(i < sampleString.length - 2) {
            sampleBuffer = sampleBuffer.plus(sampleString.toLowerCase ().substring(i, i + 2)).plus(":")
            i += 2
        }

        sampleBuffer = sampleBuffer.plus(sampleString.toLowerCase().substring(i))
        Log.e(TAG, sampleBuffer)
```

Comment: This loop is infinite :>

Comment: Did you tried ?

Comment: Yes, that's why I am saying it is infinite. While is always true.

Comment: Until sampleString is fixed length and value of "i" is incrementing inside while loop, it wont happen.