# Java substring with line break

Tags: java

Let's say I have a string:

`String pers = "PROCESS / PROGRAM / PROJECT / SERVICE DELIVERY";`

How do I break line when the string's length reaches 30? So it will result in:

PROCESS / PROGRAM / PROJECT /

SERVICE DELIVERY

My attempt:

```
String pers = "PROCESS / PROGRAM / PROJECT / SERVICE DELIVERY";
if (pers.length() > 30) {
  pers = pers.substring(0, 30) + "\n" + pers.substring(30, pers.length());
}
```

It returns `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token` at the browser's console. Please help.

Comment: Where do you use this code. Works fine when i run in eclipse IDE.

Comment: edited. typo there. thanks.

Comment: the last `substring` should not define a final length

Comment: What is the full stacktrace for your error? What line does the error point to? Please read the [ask] article...

Comment: @pavithraCS I am using Jdeveloper to run the code.

Comment: *Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token* is not being thrown from this code.  Please post the stacktrace

Comment: I guess I know why. The error is from GoJS library. Let me debug it.

Comment: The code you posted is fine. Try to clean, rebuild your program. If there are still errors, post the full stacktrace.

Comment: *The error is from GoJS library* - you are better off to delete this question

Comment: I would suggest not saying "browsers console" as most people associate that with JavaScript instead of Java, and people may downvote your question because those 2 things get confused very often.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276639/java-how-to-split-a-string-by-a-number-of-characters

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like so:

```
String pers = "PROCESS / PROGRAM / PROJECT / SERVICE DELIVERY";
String formattedString = pers.replaceAll("(.{30})", "$1\n");
```

The above should replace 30 characters with whatever is matched plus a new line character.

Answer (score 0):

A [StringBuilder](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-27-string-vs-stringbuilder-vs-stringbuffer/)  would probably be an easier way to work with string manipulation. You can try this also using String Builder.

```
String s = "A very long string containing " +
    "many many words and characters. " +
    "Newlines will be entered at spaces.";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);

int i = 0;
while ((i = sb.indexOf(" ", i + 30)) != -1) {
    sb.replace(i, i + 1, "\n");
}

System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

If you know about [Regular Expressions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/regular-expressions-in-java/) then this is the best and easiest way:-

```
String str = "....";
String parsedStr = str.replaceAll("(.{30})", "$1\n");
```

This will replace every 30 characters with the same 30 characters and add a new line at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
public ArrayList gecStringFromStringByNumberOfChars(String str, int numberOfChars) {

int numberOfLine = str.length() / numberOfChars;
int offsets = str.length() % numberOfChars;
ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLine; i++) {
    result.add(str.substring(i * numberOfChars, i * numberOfChars + numberOfChars));
}
if (offsets > 0) {
    result.add(str.substring(str.length() - offsets, str.length()));
}
return result;
}
```

in code call it gecStringFromStringByNumberOfChars(pers,30)