# How to Take every three letters from a list and saving it as an array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, for-loop, methods

How could I have every three letters of this string: `ATGCCACTATGGTAG` to be saved in an array, with a comma separating every three letters.
This is what I have:
The parameter sequence is the above jumble of letters.

```
public static void listCodons(String sequence){
      int length = sequence.length();
      String[] listOfCodons = new String[length]; 
      for(int i = 0; i< length; i++){
            //This is where I'm not sure what to do
            listOfCodons = sequence[i]+sequence[i+1]+sequence[i+2]; 
         } 
      }
      System.out.print(Arrays.toString(listOfCodons));
}
```

Comment: String has a method named substring(). Look it up in the javadoc.

Comment: @Marina Claire something like this, `listOfCodons [0] = ATG, listOfCodons [1] = TGC`.. so on

Comment: I can not see any question?

Comment: Please have a look to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297347/splitting-a-string-at-every-n-th-character

Comment: @JBNizet substrings can only be used for strings though

Comment: @MarinaClaire and what is the type of `sequence`?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this is syntactically incorrect code, there are many errors. The first one is two `}` after for loop, second one detonating end of method, so the `System.out.print` after that is out of scope of `listCodons` method, hence it's an error.

The second mistake is in java, characters in string can't be accessed with `[index]`, you have to use `.charAt(index)` instead.

If I understood your problem correctly, you want your parameter `ATGCCACTATGGTAG` to become an array of `["ATG", "CCA", "CTA", "TGG", "TAG"]`. If that's the case, here is the solution, with fixed problems:

```
public static void listCodons(String sequence) {
    int length = sequence.length();
    String[] listOfCodons = new String[length / 3];
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfCodons.length; i++) {
        listOfCodons[i] = sequence.substring(i * 3, i * 3 + 3);
    }
    System.out.print(Arrays.toString(listOfCodons));
}
```

Use 1/3 of length of sting, since we take 3 characters at a time. `i * 3` is current position at string times 3 to get to correct beginning of the tag and `i * 3 + 3` is to take next 3 characters from this position. Only problem here is if the tag length isn't consistent, but there is no information about that.

Comment: this makes an array out of bounds exception

Comment: @MarinaClaire how? I tested it, there is no way there is array out of bounds exception. I said it will not give expected output for inconsistent lengths, but it works for arbitrary string length, I tested it for lengths of 0 to 1M, it's not throwing any exceptions. Are you sure you're using exact code as posting here and that it's not something else you're doing?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the link posted by @shikjohari [answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297347/splitting-a-string-at-every-n-th-character#2297450) you could solve it like

```
public class Split {

    public static void listCodons(String sequence) {
        String[] listOfCodons = sequence.split("(?<=\\G...)");
        System.out.print(Arrays.toString(listOfCodons));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        listCodons("ATGCCACTATGGTAG");
    }
}
```

Explanation copied from the mentioned link: The regex (?<=\G...) matches an empty string that has the **last match** (\G) followed by **three characters** (...) **before it** ((?<= )).

Comment: @ManuZi I added the explanation from the posted link.

Answer (score 0):

More smarter and easier to read is the way with the [Guava Libraries](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)

That's the code:

```
public static void listCodons(String sequence)
{
    Iterable<String> pieces = Splitter.fixedLength(3).split(sequence);

    // note this is Java 8 Lambda Syntax
    pieces.forEach(pi -> System.out.println(pi));

    // If you can not use Java 8 take the following:
    for (String piece : pieces)
    {
        System.out.println(piece);
    }
}
```

Comment: Might be a bit easier to read, but harder to understand. Also, `Splitter` is not supported in standard java libraries, it's a part of [guava](https://github.com/google/guava).

Comment: What is harder to understand on this snippet? She does not have it limited to use only the standard java library.

Comment: It's not for me, but could easily be for someone new, I doubt someone new to java will jump right into new stuff of java 8. And why would one use a library just to split a string? Oh right, we're talking about java, better import 10 libraries just to get my simple test program working.

Comment: do you know about effective java? https://prezi.com/hbzxzub1ckhp/effective-java-item-47/ had she said it is for a "test program". don't get mad bro ;-)

Comment: I agree on using the libraries, but people learn to use libraries to do the smallest things and the project just grows. Learn *when* to use them, not just to use them. If you can do it with 2 more lines of native code, why add a whole library? I might be too much of DIY person, but the mirror side of this are programmers that create a dependancy hell in no time. Good luck managing project like that.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that the length of your sequence is 9, and you want to group every three characters.
This gives you the following grouping:

- characters 0, 1, and 2;
- characters 3, 4, and 5;
- characters 6, 7, and 8.

Notice how the first character in each group is indexed by a multiple of 3.
You can use this idea in your code.

```java
public static void listCodons(String sequence){
      /** If your sequence has n characters, then
      /*  dividing it into groups of three results in
      /*  n/3 groups. */
      int length = sequence.length();
      String[] listOfCodons = new String[length/3];

      for(int i = 0; i< length/3; i++) {
          /** Remember: the first character of each codon
          /*  is indexed in the sequence by a multiple
          /*  of three. */
          listOfCodons[i] = sequence.substring(3*i, 3*(i+1));
      }
      System.out.print(Arrays.toString(listOfCodons));
}
```

So what is going on?
Let's use your original example `ATGCCACTATGGTAG`.
The sequence has a length of 15.
Thus, we will get in the end 15/3=5 codons.
Each codon `i` will consist of the characters indexed by `3*i`, `3*i+1`, and `3*i+2`.
So you take the corresponding substring and add it to the list of codons.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this code :

public static void listCodons(String sequence){
        int length = (sequence.length()/3);
        String[] listOfCodons = new String[length]; 
        int j=0,i=0;
        while(i<sequence.length() && j<listOfCodons.length){
            listOfCodons[j++]=sequence.substring(i, i+3);
            i+=3;
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(listOfCodons));
    }
```