# how to split a string to several Strings by Specified number of characters in java

Tags: java, string, split, chars

I have a hypothetical string with 2500 characters. (`myString.length=2500`) and I want to split it to several strings per 500 chars and assign this new strings to an Array string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to split a String in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Comment: This question has no language tag.

Comment: Romank , this is not duplicate. muerto thanks. i added it.

Comment: can i use subString method for my purpose?

Comment: Requires the use of a library, but try: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2298477/580556

Comment: This is not a duplicate of how to split a string in java, that earlier one is about splitting around a particular character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way is to find the total split strings, and then inchworm up through the values adding the sub-strings to an ArrayList or something. Probably look a lot like this:

```
int splits = myString.length()/divisor;
int first = 0;
int second = divisor;
for (int i = 0; i < splits; i++) {
    arrayList.add(myString.substring(first, second));
    first += divisor;
    second += divisor;
}
```