# How to convert a String consisting of Binary Number to Hexa Decimal no in Java?

Tags: java

My `String` is `010101010111111111101010101010101010111101010101010101010101` and it is large in size (more than 64 characters).

I cannot use `Integer` or `Long` class parse methods due to size limitation.

Expected Output would be `557FEAAAAF55555h`.

Comment: Have you tried `BigInteger`?

Comment: Did you try BigNumber ?

Comment: @prasun What's `BigNumber`?

Comment: my bad its BigInteger, more used to JS so, made this mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `BigInteger` for this:

```
String s = "010101010111111111101010101010101010111101010101010101010101";
BigInteger value = new BigInteger(s, 2);
System.out.println(value.toString(16));
```

This shows:

```
557feaaaaf55555
```

Or to get your exact output:

```
System.out.println(value.toString(16).toUpperCase() + "h");
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know your performance requirements, but it seems to me you could simply:

1. Split your string into nibbles of 4 (see [Splitting a string at every n-th character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297347/splitting-a-string-at-every-n-th-character));
2. Then convert each of them into an integer (see [Converting String to Int in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/converting-string-to-int-in-java));
3. And finally and concatenate their hexadecimal value (see [Java.lang.Integer.toHexString() Method](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/integer_tohexstring.htm)).

Comment: This is a good approach, but you have to handle the case where the input string isn't a multiple of 4.

Comment: Agreed. You could still use the length of the string, modulo 4 and use the result as the number of "0" to prefix the string (if it's not a stream). However `BigInteger` is much more elegant and faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
   public  String GetHex(String binary){
        String[] parts=binary.split("(?<=\\G.{4})");
        String output="";
        for(String s: parts)
        {
            output+=Integer.toHexString(Integer.parseInt(s, 2));
        }
    }
```

And Call it with your Binary String

```
 String binary="010101010111111111101010101010101010111101010101010101010101";
     String hexvalue=GetHex(binary); //557feaaaaf55555
```