# Map reduce job for continue stream

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a huge text file which contains text data . Files' each line contains 12 character of data. I need to find a substring of 5 character from that file using map reduce job.

Input file.

```
abcdefghijkl
kahfdjshjsdh
sdfkjsdjkjks
```

value to search

```
cdefg
```

The 'cdefg' can occurs anywhere in the file. It can be in in two lines. So I don't know how to create a map of last two character of current line and next 3 character of next line.

Comment: @bouteillebleu I wrote a simple program which is giving me line by of input string and split that line in 5 character and create a map for that but don't know how to handle last 2 characters of input string.

Comment: you want to return the line which contain `cdefg` ?

Comment: I have created map in mapper and later will match with "cdefg" string, but my question how I can create maps of 5 characters.

Comment: Use an array of character `Character[]` !

Comment: @YCF_L Don't understand that, do you have an example.

Comment: i really don't understand your question also, can you explain more?

Comment: I have a file containing lines of 12 characters and I want to find 5 character of string from that file. In Mapper I am getting 12 character of line and can create two maps of 5 character and left 2 character and want to get next 3 character from next line and want to create map of it. So in reducer I can compare that maps with my string.

Comment: so your inputs should look like this `[abcde, fghij, klkah, fdjsh, jsdhs, dfkjs, djkjk, s]` ?

Comment: check my answer hope this can gives you an idea

Answer (score 0):

> I have a file containing lines of 12 characters and I want to find 5
>   character of string from that file. In Mapper I am getting 12
>   character of line and can create two maps of 5 character and left 2
>   character and want to get next 3 character from next line and want to
>   create map of it. So in reducer I can compare that maps with my
>   string.

You can concatenate your line all together then you can split the result with 5 character check this [Splitting a string at every n-th character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297347/splitting-a-string-at-every-n-th-character) :

```
abcdefghijklkahfdjshjsdhsdfkjsdjkjks
[abcde, fghij, klkah, fdjsh, jsdhs, dfkjs, djkjk, s]
```

You can inspire the solution from this piece of code :

```
File file = new File("myFile.txt");
try {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    String result = "";
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        result += line;
    }
    System.out.println(result);
    //here you can use this array
    String spl[] = result.split("(?<=\\G.....)");

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(spl));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Output**

```
abcdefghijklkahfdjshjsdhsdfkjsdjkjks
[abcde, fghij, klkah, fdjsh, jsdhs, dfkjs, djkjk, s]
```

**EDIT**

> I Want to create map like this abcdefghijklkahfdjshjsdhsdfkjsdjkjks
>   [abcde, bcdef, cdefg, defgh... ]

You can solve this problem like so :

```
String str = "abcdefghijklkahfdjshjsdhsdfkjsdjkjks";
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < str.length()-4; i++) {
    String s = "";
    for (int j = i; j < i+5; j++) {
        s+=result.charAt(j);
    }
    list.add(s);
}
```

**Output**

```
[abcde, bcdef, cdefg, defgh, efghi, fghij, ghijk, ...., djkjk, jkjks]
```

Comment: I Want to create map like this 
abcdefghijklkahfdjshjsdhsdfkjsdjkjks
[abcde, bcdef, cdefg, defgh... ]

Comment: 2ndly need to concatenate last 2 characters with next line start character

Comment: so the last value of your array should be `jkjks` right @IbrarAhmed ?

Comment: My next line is "hasjfdkjksjkdfjsalkdjf" so next maps should be [jkjks,kjksh, jksha, kshas, shasj ....

Comment: yes my solution do what you want did you try it @IbrarAhmed

Comment: Yes try it, it start again for next line, I want to resume scanning from first line, like last 4 character of first line and one character from second line and the last 3 character from first file and first two character from second line.

Comment: I cannot concatenate all lines because they are too many, need a solution which is getting just next line, [I need it in mapper ]

Comment: mmm, ok i will try to find a solution when i will be free, it need more concentration @IbrarAhmed