# Splitting strings in between 3rd and 4th characters in R

Tags: r, string, stringr

I'm grabbing information from Wikipedia on Canadian Forward Sortation Areas (FSAs - those are the first 3 digits of postal codes in Canada) and what cities/areas they belong to. Example of this information is below:

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

URL <- paste0("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes_of_Canada:_", "K")

FSAs <- URL %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath = "//td") %>% 
  html_text()

head(FSAs)
[1] "K1AGovernment of CanadaOttawa and Gatineau offices (partly in QC)\n"            "K2AOttawa(Highland Park / McKellar Park /Westboro /Glabar Park /Carlingwood)\n"
[3] "K4AOttawa(Fallingbrook)\n"                                                      "K6AHawkesbury\n"                                                               
[5] "K7ASmiths Falls\n"                                                              "K8APembrokeCentral and northern subdivisions\n"
```

The problem I'm facing is that I would like to have a data frame with the first 3 digits of each spring in one column, and the rest of the information in another. I've thought there would be a solution involving a `stringr` function like `str_split()`, but this removes the pattern of the first 3 digits, which I of course don't want. In effect, I'm looking to split the string in-between the 3rd and 4th character of each string.

I've figured out this solution, with the last bit borrowed from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2297450/5221626), but it's incredibly hackish. My question is, is there a better way of doing this?

```
FSAs %>% 
  enframe(name = NULL) %>%
  separate(value, c(NA, "Location"), sep = "^...", remove = FALSE) %>% 
  separate(value, c("FSA", NA), sep = "(?<=\\G...)")

# A tibble: 195 x 2
   FSA   Location                                                                     
   <chr> <chr>                                                                        
 1 K1A   "Government of CanadaOttawa and Gatineau offices (partly in QC)\n"           
 2 K2A   "Ottawa(Highland Park / McKellar Park /Westboro /Glabar Park /Carlingwood)\n"
 3 K4A   "Ottawa(Fallingbrook)\n"                                                     
 4 K6A   "Hawkesbury\n"                                                               
 5 K7A   "Smiths Falls\n"                                                             
 6 K8A   "PembrokeCentral and northern subdivisions\n"                                
 7 K9A   "Cobourg\n"                                                                  
 8 K1B   "Ottawa(Blackburn Hamlet / Pine View / Sheffield Glen)\n"                    
 9 K2B   "Ottawa(Britannia /Whitehaven / Bayshore / Pinecrest)\n"                     
10 K4B   "Ottawa(Navan)\n"
```

Comment: See the function: `substr()`, one can specify the start and stop positions. For example: `substr(x, 1, 3)`

Comment: `data.frame(FSA = substring(FSAs, 1, 3), Location = substring(FSAs, 4))` works, thanks.