# How do i split a string every five characters using loops?

Tags: java, regex, string

Suppose I have a string: "VJKUKUTGCNNAUVWRKF"
How can I use loops to make it into this instead
"VJKUK UTGCN NAUVW RKF" where there is a space every
five characters (notice the last part only has three characters).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Splitting a string at every n-th character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297347/splitting-a-string-at-every-n-th-character)

Comment: This is not a duplicate. OP asked specifically about using loops.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps

```
String str = "VJKUKUTGCNNAUVWRKF";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int j = 1; j <= str.length(); j++) {
        
    sb.append(str.charAt(j-1));
        
    if (j % 5 == 0) {
        sb.append(" ");
    }
}

String str2 = sb.toString();
```

I don't think it's a perfectly optimized solution, but it is one way.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using java8 or higher :

```
String original  = "VJKUKUTGCNNAUVWRKF";

String modifided = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\G.{5})")
                          .splitAsStream(original)
                          .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```

Comment: The OP specifically mentioned using loops.

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.substring()` and concatenate.

```
String s = "JJGDVKJGFGKKGRFJJF";
String result="";

for (int i=0;i<s.length;i+=5) {
    if(!result.equals("") result+=" ";
    result+=s.substring(i, Math.max(i+5, s.length));
}
```

I'm writing from my mobile. So it's difficult to make a good code. There may be a few mistakes to correct.

Comment: still a little new to java could you elaborate on how to use String.substring()

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use regex please refer this

[Splitting a string at every n-th character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297347/splitting-a-string-at-every-n-th-character)

Code:

```
    String s = "VJKUKUTGCNNAUVWRKF";
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(s.split("(?<=\\G.....)")));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some variables to keep track of the index positions and use `substring(startIndex, endIndex)` to update the new string. We use `StringBuilder` to create the new String.

```
String first = "VJKUKUTGCNNAUVWRKF";
StringBuilder splittedString = new StringBuilder();
int length = first.length();
int index = 0;
    
while(length > 0){
    int endIndex = index + 5;
    if(length <= 5){
        endIndex = index + length;
    }
        
    splittedString.append(first.substring(index, endIndex));
    splittedString.append(" ");
    length -= 5;
    index += 5;
}
    
System.out.println(splittedString.toString().trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

@Aharon already give you a good solution, but it could produce redundant " " when the String length is a multiple of 5.
This could fix the case and be a little more efficient and organized:

```
public static String split(String s, int size, String sep) {

    if (s.length() <= size) {
        return s;
    }

    final int expectedLength = s.length() + s.length() / size;

    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(expectedLength);

    sb.append(s, 0, size);

    int counter = 2 * size;

    while (counter <= s.length()) {
        sb.append(sep).append(s, counter - size, counter);
        counter += size;
    }

    if (counter - size < s.length()) {
        sb.append(sep).append(s, counter - size, s.length());
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

So you can just call:

```
String s = "VJKUKKASDD";

String out = split(s, 5, " ");
```