# In JAVA, how do you split a text file in three characters?

Tags: java, split

I want to split a text file that has all connected words "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
I want my output to print:

```
ABC
DEF
GHI
JKL
```

I tried:

```
String text = StdIn.readAll();
String parts [] = text.split("\\s ",3);
for(String a: parts)
    System.out.println(a);
```

Comment: Looks like a job for [`substring`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,int)) rather then regex

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2297450/3792469 - relevant answers - `s.split("(?<=\\G...)"))`

Answer (score 2):

This answer should work, see this similar post [Split string to equal length substrings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760152/split-string-to-equal-length-substrings-in-java).

```
String[] parts = text.split("(?<=\\G.{3})");
```

Comment: Hiya, nice find, but for future - if you found an existing similar question with an answer, it is better to mark this question as duplicate rather than copy information over and over again from post to post :)

Comment: Thankss! Please if you can explain what each part of this means ("(?<=\\G.{3})")

Comment: @NemanjaM If you click on the link, another user has explained it there.

Answer (score 1):

Insert a separator with `replaceAll`, then split the string with `split`.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String text = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    String parts[] = text.replaceAll("(.{3})", "$1,").split(",");
    
    for (String a : parts)
        System.out.println(a);
}
```

Result:

```plain
ABC
DEF
GHI
JKL
MNO
PQR
STU
VWX
YZ
```

Answer (score 1):

`.substring()` solution:

```
String text = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
for(int i= 0; i < text.length(); i+=3)
  System.out.println((i+3 <= text.length() ? text.substring(i, i+3) : text.substring(i)));
```

Result:

```
ABC
DEF
GHI
JKL
MNO
PQR
STU
VWX
YZ
```

Comment: Not compatible with all Unicode characters. Run with: ` "ABDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"` as input. Output: AB?
?DE
FGH