# Access C++ code in C# application performance

Tags: c#, c++, performance, dll, external

I'm thinking about running a function written in C++ in a C# application, whether it's mobile or normal one.

Is running that code written in C++(math processing) in a C# environment(application) faster or about the same if that same code(theoretical) is written in C#?

Thank you!

second question: How can i contain and access C++ code in a C# application, without externally access it from a DLL?

Comment: As a first guess, if you want something like `-ffast-math`, I believe C++ might give you some boost. Otherwise it could be either not worth the bother OR worth be made into SSE and not just any C++. UPD: And you cannot do much of "++" across the boundary. Plain C-style calls, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

Check this 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998551.aspx

Comment: -1. While link itself is useful, the format of an answer is not good for SO: please either add links as comments OR please provide relevant summary of the linked article along with the link.

Answer (score 0):

Although you can come close in C# usually the C++ version is faster (in my experience). The C++ optimizing compilers do a better job (can take longer to compile/optimize) and also in C++ you can use stuff like SSE to speed math stuff up, which is very cumbersome from C#. I have created code for large integer multiplication that is 5x faster in SSE as in assembler, which was only 10% faster as the same C++ code. The 5x came mostly from SSE being able to do 2x 32bit multiplies with a single instruction.

C# allows for unsafe code where you can do some pointer stuff. Speeding up things like array processing (as it normally bounds checks all array access this helps for array intense math processing). And you can fall back to using unmanaged DLL's written in C++

So unless your code will run for hours at an end I think optimizing it will probably be fun, but not really worth it ;-)

There was/is a C++/CLI variant for .NET from microsoft, allowing for easier mixing of C++ and C#. See http://www.functionx.com/cppcli/Lesson01.htm But not sure it that is still supported and from what I gathered it was frowned upon from the start, not sure why though.

You might also find this stack exchange question interesting about why VirtualMachine Languages differ in performance compared to precompiled ones; [Why are JIT-ed languages still slower and less memory efficient than native C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11881853/why-are-jit-ed-languages-still-slower-and-less-memory-efficient-than-native-c-c/11882820#11882820)