# What is "Process Killed" in C++?

Tags: c++

I was trying to make a game with C++ and noticed that there is `Process Killed` in the 4th line of the output. I am just curious about what is it.

### My Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;

class Health {
    public:
    int Nhealth = 1000;
    int Mhealth = 1000;
};

class AttackMagicPower : public Health { // You can ignore this function
    public:
    int MagicAttackCommand;
    
    void AttackMagicPowerPlan() {
        cin >> MagicAttackCommand;
        if (MagicAttackCommand = 1) {
            Mhealth = Mhealth - 200;
        }
    }
};

class Enemy {
    public:
    void coutx() {
        srand(time(0) + time(0));
        string a[3];
        a[0] = "Monster! - PUNCH";
        a[1] = "Monster! - KICK";
        a[2] = "Monster! - COMBO";
        int randomcout = (rand() % 3);
        cout << a[randomcout] << endl;
        cout << "#########################" << endl;
    }
};

class Character {
    public:
    int startSTOPmatch;
    void coutxy() {
        string coutt;
        cout << "Enter Your Command" << endl;
        cin >> coutt;
        if (coutt == "KICK" || coutt == "PUNCH" || coutt == "COMBO") {
            cout << "#########################" << endl;
            cout << "Ninja! - " << coutt << endl;
            startSTOPmatch = 1;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Your Command Was Wrong...You Lost The Match" << endl;
            cout << "You May Retry!" << endl;
            startSTOPmatch = 0;
        }
    }
};

class mainx : public Health, public Character {
    public:
    mainx() {
        int random = (rand() % 10);
        Enemy e;
        cout << "Ladies and Gentlemen! Welcome to the fight of a Ninja and a Monstor\n";
        sleep(1.0);
        cout << "Hope You Will Enjoy!\n";
        sleep(0.5);
        cout << "__________________________________________________________";
        cout << "_____________\n\n" << endl;
        cout << "You and the monster can perform the following actions - \nKICK, ";
        cout << "PUNCH, COMBO" << endl;
        sleep(2.0);
        cout << "_____________________________" << endl;
        cout << "Monster Health - 1000" << endl;
        cout << "Ninja Health - 1000" << endl;
        cout << "_____________________________" << endl;
        cout << " " << endl;
        sleep(1.0);
            do {
                
                srand(time(0));
                int randomHealthLowNormal = (rand() % 101);
                srand(time(0) + random);
                int xandomHealthLowNormal = (rand() % 101);
                Mhealth = Mhealth - randomHealthLowNormal;
                Nhealth = Nhealth - xandomHealthLowNormal;
                coutxy();
                if (startSTOPmatch = 1) {
                    e.coutx();
                    sleep(1.0);
                    cout << "_____________________________" << endl;
                    cout << "Monster Health - " << Mhealth << endl;
                    cout << "Ninja Health - " << Nhealth << endl;
                    cout << "_____________________________" << endl;
                    cout << " " << endl;
                    cout << " " << endl;
                    cout << " " << endl;
                    sleep(3.0);
                } else {
                    cout << " " << endl;
                }
           } while (Mhealth > 0 || Nhealth > 0);
        if (Nhealth < 0 || Nhealth == 0 || startSTOPmatch == 0) {
                cout << "Monster Won The Match!" << endl;
            }
            else if (Mhealth < 0 || Mhealth == 0) {
                cout << "Ninja Won The Match!" << endl;
            }
    }
};

int main() {
    mainx m;
    return 0;
}
```

### My Output

```
+ g++ -w -Wall -std=c++14 -O2 -o main.out main.cpp -lm


Process Killed.


+ ./main.out

>>>Ladies and Gentlemen! Welcome to the fight of a Ninja and a Monster

>>>Hope You Will Enjoy!
_______________________________________________________________________


>>>
You and the monster can perform the following actions - 
KICK, PUNCH, COMBO

>>>_____________________________
Monster Health - 1000
Ninja Health - 1000
_____________________________
 

>>>Enter Your Command
>>>
```

Comment: It might be caused by the host not having enough RAM for g++ to work properly.

Comment: Have you tried the `g++ -w -Wall -std=c++14 -O2 -o main.out main.cpp -lm` command again? Is there something in your `dmesg` like OOM_Killer?

Comment: Probably not related, but you have a couple of cases where you use `=` where I think you mean `==`.

Comment: `srand(time(0) + time(0));` I see that you prevent it from being called more than 1 time per second however I would just seed the random number generator 1 time in `int main()` instead of reseeding mostly for each random number.

Comment: `if (x = 1)` sets x to 1, then since non-zero is *truthy*, it results in `true` expression for the if predicate.  `srand` should only be called once, probably near the beginning of the `main` block.  The `mainx` constructor is doing way too much.  A constructor should just do construction — move that to a `void run_loop()` method of `mainx`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What Is The Meaning Of “Process Killed” In C++?

It is probably a message given by your [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) since [processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) are unknown to C++. I guess that if your OS is Unix-like or POSIX (e.g. MacOSX, Linux), that message was output by your Linux or [Unix shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) (perhaps [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) or [zsh](https://zsh.org/)). You need to understand what process was killed. On Linux, see [signal(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) and [ps(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html), [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html), [top(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html).

I recommend reading a good [textbook on operating systems](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/OSTEP/). Perhaps start writing your own OS, see [OSDEV](https://osdev.org/) for more.

I also recommend reading some good [C++ programming book](https://www.stroustrup.com/programming.html), and the documentation of your C++ compiler, e.g. [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang/LLVM](https://clang.llvm.org/).

> `g++ -w -Wall -std=c++14 -O2 -o main.out main.cpp -lm`

Try at least `g++ -Wall -Wextra -std=c++14 -O2 -g -o main.out main.cpp -lm` then use [gdb(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gdb.1.html). You could even be interested in the [`-fanalyzer` option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Static-Analyzer-Options.html#Static-Analyzer-Options) to recent GCC.

Once you have read a good C++ programming book, consider looking inside this [C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) website, and read the documentation of your debugger, e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/).

Later read some C++ draft standard, perhaps [n4849](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/n4849.pdf)

Study also for inspiration the source code of existing C++ open source programs or libraries (e.g. on [github](https://github.com/) or [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/)), such as [Fish](https://fishshell.com/), [Qt](https://qt.io/), [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/), [FLTK](https://www.fltk.org/) and of course both  [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) and [Clang/LLVM](https://clang.llvm.org/).

Consider perhaps writing your own [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) to analyze (and detect *some* bugs at compile-time) your C++ code. Or consider using the [Clang static analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) or [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/) (or perhaps in 2021 my [Bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon) described in [this draft](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf) report funded by [CHARIOT](https://www.chariotproject.eu/) & [DECODER](https://www.decoder-project.eu/) projects)

Be however aware of theoretical limitations such as [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem).

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65129497/841108). It might interest you.

> (Note: It is my first game project so if there are any game developers here, please suggest me how to get started with pixel game development in the comments)

Use some libraries, such as [libSFML](https://www.sfml-dev.org/) or [Qt](https://qt.io/) or [libSDL](https://www.libsdl.org/). You might want to also use [Wt](https://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt) or [sqlite](https://sqlite.org/). If on Linux, [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) might be interesting too. BTW, you'll have more fun in joining some *existing* [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-source_software) project than in working alone on your own one.

Comment: This is how to schedule oneself 20 years of studying computer science :D

Comment: I would rather say 40 years. I start studying computer science in 1975, and my late father was himself a computer scientist (the author of the first commercial French compiler, [PAF](http://www.feb-patrimoine.com/english/paf_starynkevitcha.htm))

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch interesting. Thanks for sharing

Comment: The funny thing is that `PAF` was very `BASIC`-like, but appeared in 1959.  BASIC appeared in 1984. I was lucky to code on a [CAB 500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAB500) computer (in a Paris Museum) in PAF. That CAB 500 thing was as old as I am, and my own father coded its compiler.