# I using bit manipulation but it isn't quick enough? Is it because of Scanner class?

Tags: time-complexity, bitwise-xor

This is the Question:

> https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/find-the-odd-occurence/0
>
> Given an array of positive integers where all numbers occur even
>   number of times except one number which occurs odd number of times.
>   Find the number.

---

Input can range from

> 1 ≤ T ≤ 100  : Test Cases
>   1 ≤ N ≤ 107  : Number of inputs
>   1 ≤ A[i] ≤ 106 : Inputs

---

Example:

```
Input:

1
5
8 4 4 8 23

Output:

23
```

---

This is code:

```
class GFG
 {
    public static void main (String[] args)
     {
     //code
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = sc.nextInt();
        while(t-->0){
              int N = sc.nextInt();
              int count = 0;
              for(int j = 0; j<N; j++){
                  int in = sc.nextInt();
                 count =count^in;
              }
              System.out.println(count);
        }

    }
}
```

My question is, The OJ took **2.5s** to execute it and other people did this in significantly less time than mine. Some did it in **0.3s**. And that too including inputting the numbers in an array and then iterating through them.

---

Why is that, Is this because of OJ or what, I didn't get it? 
Also I did the submission several times just to make sure there if there was a fault but all the time it took more than 2.5s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modern Java is considered quite fast, if you write optimised code, but it is still slower than languages which interact at a even lower level and have a ahead-of-time compiler. Anyways this topic has a very nice elaborated answer here : [Is Java really slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163411/is-java-really-slow).

However your java code can still be optimised by using `BufferedReader` instead of directly using `Scanner`. `Scanner` actually takes a input stream and then parses according to the datatype we try to fetch, but `BufferedReader` just gives you a raw input and does no operations. Hence if you use it and parse your raw input line separately, it will be much better for your code runtime. I was able to get 0.61s with slightly modified version of your code using `BufferedReader` :

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
class gfg
{
    public static void main(String args []) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(System.out, true);
        int t=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        while(t-->0)
        {
            int N = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            String str[]=br.readLine().split(" ");
            int count = 0;
            for(int j = 0; j<N; j++){
                int in = Integer.parseInt(str[j]);
                count =count^in;
              }
              System.out.println(count);
        }

    }
}
```

I think with some more optimizations you can probably, bring the time almost comparable to 0.3s.

Comment: This is the right answer; `Scanner` is often just too slow for competitive programming challenges, so +1. As an alternative to BufferedReader, consider using a fast IO library which is designed for competitive programming, such as this one https://github.com/sagar-rathod/Fast-Java-Input-Output/blob/master/Fast%20Java%20IO/src/com/sagarrathod/fastio/BufferInput.java . You can use it like a `Scanner`, because it has `nextInt` and so on, but it's much faster because it just assumes the input is valid (so there's no error-checks). That's a safe assumption in competitive programming challenges.

Comment: what does "while(t-->0) does?