# Java NIO vs DotNet IO Performance

Tags: java, .net, performance, file-io

Does anyone know what the performance difference is between
Java NIO vs DotNet IO performance.

Reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145110/c-performance-vs-java-c) question, it seems that standard Java-IO and DotNet-IO have
very similar IO performance.

What is interesting to me is that the Java guys state that mass file copying, file server based operations...etc should be a lot quicker because of access to the file channels etc in Java-NIO.

Is it possible that `java.nio` performance is better than DotNet `System.IO`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as far as file copying, there shouldn't be significant differences, no matter what platform or api you are using. the bottle neck is the disk spinning and head seeking of the hard drive. *

what needs to happen, is to move content of harddisk to some memory, then write the memory to harddisk. with traditional java io stream, there will be extra memory copies. still that's not significant waste compared to disk speed.

this can be easily verified, FileChannel.transferTo/From cannot beat old way of input-output stream copying by much.

(*) of course, there are much faster disks now, but as long as we define disk as the next slower storage after memory, the argument holds.

(**)we could call a virtual disk a disk, which actually resides in main memory. then memory copy is the bottle neck, and the argument doesn't hold any more.

Answer (score 3):

I actually can not answer this, but I can think freely...

.. both Java-File-IO and .Net should use underlaying OS operations for file access, and file access is always IO bound and not CPU bound. Meaning that disks are slower then CPU and memory.

What this would mean is that Java-File-IO and .Net should be the same in terms of performance.

When it comes to Socket communication Java did a horrible work, and actually just ignore the Posix standard and didn't use OS call 'select'. This was fixed in Java NIO with the introduction of "channels" that is nothing more then actually supporting the underlaying architecture. Before you needed to allocated a thread for every socket you was reading on, horrible wastage of resources.

Since .Net is newer then Java, I would believe that they never fell into this trap and added support for this from the start.. But I haven't used .Net so I can tell, I can not guess.

Regarding Socket communication in both cases Java-NIO and .Net System.IO, both should be network bound before they become CPU bound anyhow. So I don't think one would be faster then the other.

Comment: Java NIO does not perform faster than Java IO on modern day hardware with modern day OSs.  See: [Old is new Again](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/java-io-faster-than-nio-old-is-new-again/).  He states that "the extremely low-cost to thread synchronization that exists in modern operating systems combined with the explosion of multi-cored systems" is a factor in why blocking IO is out performing non blocking IO in Java.

Comment: From a comment on that article: "Throughput is not the point of NIO. The point of non-blocking IO is to be able to handle millions of simultaneous slow connections with fast response times – a case where threads would just blow the stack and drop connections after accepting a few thousands."