# .net components in unmanaged code - performance?

Tags: c#, .net, c++, com

I need to write some dll that will be loaded into some existing system via COM. How much performance do I lose if I write using c#.net instead of plain c++?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145110/c-performance-vs-java-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, none.

Things to watch out for:

- Creating lots of strings by performing lots of string concats; but that in itself won't necessarily be a problem
- Excessive Boxing/Unboxing

[Performance (C# and Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173196%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)