# What are specific differences between coding styles of Java and C++?

Tags: java, c++, coding-style

This question has been on my mind for a while. I used C++ for some web development I was doing, and also some hobby programming. The only reason I got into it a little was because of the web development thing, as I just used plain C before. All in all, I didn't use C++ too extensively.

Recently, I've been doing more extensive work with Java. Lots of people say that C++ and Java are completely different, and that doing thing the 'Java way' isn't a good idea for programming in C++, suggesting that they are two completely different worlds. They certainly *feel* different, and function differently. But more specifically, what do people mean when they say that?

Are they talking about garbage collection? Or something else?

Thanks

Comment: They are talking about *everything*. It's the whole mindset that differs between C++ and Java.

Comment: Probably best served by asking on programmers.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Xeo: Haha. Comments like yours are exactly what I was referring to. :) I get the different mindset, but more specifically, what are the style differences?

Comment: if you can't absolutely understand it, its C++

Comment: @Hassan: Java shoehorns everything into classes. Everything has to derive from `Object`. C++ let's you do as you please, you can have free function, aswell as member functions. Same with the inheritance. If you need a Java-like hierarchy, you need to build it yourself, because C++ doesn't need it. We have templates that are far more powerful than anything Java has to offer (no bashing, this is a fact). They allow duck-typing so that we don't need a uniform interface to operate between objects.

Comment: On the other hand, Java is a more *productive* language, just because so much is done for you already. If you however want to disable certain parts? Well, tough luck. Now, if I continue any further, I think I'll derail into bashing...

Comment: @Xeo: Thanks for the insight. Like I said, I only used C++ for a small web application, and probably didn't utilize 10% of its capabilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main difference is due to the fact that with Java you are running a program on a virtual environment (Java Virtual Machine) that you do not know, and that you are not allowed to access deeply.

This obviously generats a lot of differences, regarding level of programming and efficiency.

You can check this interesting link I found: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_performance

And this SO question: [C++ performance vs. Java/C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145110/c-performance-vs-java-c)

Speaking in general terms C++ allows you to have more low level control of your programming.

e.g Java garbage collector manages memory without you knowing what it does:

1. you don't know when it starts
2. you don't know how it works
3. . . .

instead in C++ if you want a sort of garbage collector module you must manage memory allocations by yourself.

Comment: Yes, but C++ can be used for user applications. Even then, people would suggest that they are entirely different.

Comment: @Hassan working low-level doesn't mean you can't program user applications...

Comment: "instead in C++ you must manage memory allocations." -- Must you?  I don't do any memory management in C++.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley If you wish to implement a sort of garbage collector module you must implement it by your self

Comment: @Matteo: If I want garbage collection, I go to Java or C#. In C++, we have smart pointers.

Comment: @Matteo: Okay, but why would I want that when I can just create objects with automatic storage that will destroy themselves at the end of the scope?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley mine was just a fast and direct example of difference in low vs high level way of programming, I didn't say that it should be smart to implement it. I agree that probably I could have found a better example, but it was the first that came up in my mind since Hassan cited it..

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Not all data structures can be freed purely based on scope.  Sometimes you need to use a heap, rather than a stack.

Comment: @Matteo but you know how your malloc-free mechanism works in C++?

Comment: @PeterLawrey: That's why we have copy constructors and return values.  And for objects that cannot or should not be copied, we have smart pointers, which themselves are still stack based.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen you're talking about new() and delete()?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley While stack based it is still managed memory because you don't have to explicitly free up the memory.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Exactly right, that was my original point.  That in C++, just because we don't have built-in garbage collection, doesn't mean we have to manually manage memory, ever.  ~90% of the time, we just use automatic storage, where in Java you would use dynamic storage.  When we need dynamic storage, we have smart pointers, or container classes.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley C++ still has the option of using a garbage collector, but using automatic storage is more the C++ way.  Java's allocation is efficient up to the point you need to perform a collection.  What Java lacks is the option to use objects on the stack or automatic collection.  Personally, I think allocating on the stack is a real improvement which the JVM has only limited optimisations to work around. (It can eliminate the object allocation, but rarely does) IMHO, The automatic allocation feels more like a hack or an after thought to me.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: We are in agreement, I think.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://www.dickbaldwin.com/java/Java008.htm) article, as well as [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Java_and_C++) one can help you with this matter. As to actually working with languages, I find C++ easier to work with, and giving me much more freedom over my data than Java does.

Answer (score 0):

There so many specific differences between a high level language like Java and a low level language like C++ that it would be best to leave it to Wikipedia to list them out: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Java_and_C%2B%2B

I strongly recommend building out a project in both of them to get a better understanding. The similarities really stop at the syntax.

Comment: The link I posted was to C++, not C.

Comment: I've updated the text to be clearer I was referencing C++.