# C++ vector's insert & push_back difference

Tags: c++

I want to know what are difference(s) between `vector`'s `push_back` and `insert` functions.

Is there a structural difference(s)?

Is there a really big performance difference(s)?

Comment: `insert` can do it anywhere, and includes other things like ranges support. `push_back` is more convenient for adding onto the end.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

The biggest difference is their functionality. `push_back` always puts a new element at the end of the `vector` and `insert` allows you to select new element's position. This impacts the performance. `vector` elements are moved in the memory only when it's necessary to increase it's length because too little memory was allocated for it. On the other hand `insert` forces to move all elements after the selected position of a new element. You simply have to make a place for it. This is why `insert` might often be less efficient than `push_back`.

Comment: On the other hand, inserting at the end should be as efficient as `push_back`.

Comment: Well, almost as efficient -- the code needs to determine that the `insert` is actually at the `end()`, so there are going to be more branches in `insert` than in `push_back`, unless the compiler can figure out that they actually aren't needed.

Comment: @TomerW People choose C or C++ to be able to sqeeze every single machine cycle they can, to increase the performance, to the point of sometimes writing directly in ASM... every "if" counts, this is not java..

Comment: @Cesar Its not why you choose your lang... cpp can be faster then c, and vice versa... hell, in some cases even java can be faster then c for its Runtime optimizations.

Comment: @TomerW ho, so why? enlighten me please.

Comment: @Cesar great Attitude, though i'd still answer. 1. C++ is object oriented 2. C++ has many additional libs and resources to use. 3. C++ Templating Engine can make your code more efficient. 4. C++ is more fun to write (comments, mid scope variables, etc...) 5. Exception mechanism can make your design different. 6. namespaces can make your code more scalable.  There are more, but i think you get the point.

Comment: @Cesar BTW: As for Managed surpassing Native performance (in some situations)... go read about the JIT Optimizations... start at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145110/c-performance-vs-java-c  nowadays, Java has a RT-Java which also introduce determinism and preemptive scheduling too. Hope you now see the light :)

Comment: @TomerW Probably it worth nothing as it is run just on a toy software, but is still an interesting banckmark: http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/

Answer (score 34):

The functions have different purposes. [`vector::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) allows you to insert an object at a specified position in the `vector`, whereas [`vector::push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) will just stick the object on the end. See the following example:

```
using namespace std;
vector<int> v = {1, 3, 4};
v.insert(next(begin(v)), 2);
v.push_back(5);
// v now contains {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

You can use `insert` to perform the same job as `push_back` with `v.insert(v.end(), value)`.

Answer (score 10):

Beside the fact, that `push_back(x)` does the same as `insert(x, end())` (maybe with slightly better performance), there are several important thing to know about these functions:

1. `push_back` exists only on `BackInsertionSequence` containers - so, for example, it doesn't exist on `set`. It couldn't because `push_back()` grants you that it will always add at the end.
2. Some containers can also satisfy `FrontInsertionSequence` and they have `push_front`. This is satisfied by `deque`, but not by `vector`.
3. The `insert(x, ITERATOR)` is from `InsertionSequence`, which is common for `set` and `vector`. This way you can use either `set` or `vector` as a target for multiple insertions. However, `set` has additionally `insert(x)`, which does practically the same thing (this first insert in `set` means only to speed up searching for appropriate place by starting from a different iterator - a feature not used in this case).

Note about the last case that if you are going to add elements in the loop, then doing `container.push_back(x)` and `container.insert(x, container.end())` will do effectively the same thing. However this won't be true if you get this `container.end()` first and then use it in the whole loop.

For example, you could **risk** the following code:

```
auto pe = v.end();
for (auto& s: a)
    v.insert(s, pe);
```

This will effectively copy whole `a` into `v` vector, **in reverse order**, and only if you are lucky enough to not get the vector reallocated for extension (you can prevent this by calling `reserve()` first); if you are not so lucky, you'll get so-called UndefinedBehavior(tm). Theoretically this isn't allowed because vector's iterators are considered invalidated every time a new element is added.

If you do it this way:

```
copy(a.begin(), a.end(), back_inserter(v);
```

it will copy `a` at the end of `v` in the original order, and this doesn't carry a risk of iterator invalidation.

[EDIT] I made previously this code look this way, and it was a mistake because `inserter` actually maintains the validity and advancement of the iterator:

```
copy(a.begin(), a.end(), inserter(v, v.end());
```

So this code will also add all elements in the original order without any risk.

Comment: Your remarks about std::inserter being "risky" for vector-like containers are incorrect. In fact, it's designed to eliminate these risks. No reverse ordering, no undefined behavior. See e.g. 
https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/10/06/stl-inserter-iterators-work/
for a breakdown.

Comment: You're right. I just wanted to make the code short instead of expanding it into an extensive manual loop, so this is actually not true because `inserter` maintains the advancement and validity of the iterator. I'll have to edit the post :)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see it in any of the comments above but it is important to know:

If we wish to add a new element to a given vector and the new size of the vector (including the new element) surpasses the current vector capacity it will cause an automatic reallocation of the allocated storage space.
And Beacuse memory allocation is an action we wish to minimize it will increase the capacity **both in push_back and insert** in the same way (for a vector with n elemeny will add about n/2).

So in terms of memory efficiency it is safe to say, use what ever you like best.
for example:

```
std::vector<int> test_Insert = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 };
std::vector<int> test_Push_Back = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 };

std::cout << test_Insert.capacity() << std::endl;
std::cout << test_Push_Back.capacity() << std::endl;

test_Insert.push_back(8);
test_Push_Back.insert(test_Push_Back.end(), 8);

std::cout << test_Insert.capacity() << std::endl;
std::cout << test_Push_Back.capacity() << std::endl;
```

This code will print:

7

7

10

10

Answer (score 1):

Since there's no actual performance data, I reluctantly wrote some code to produce it. Keep in mind that I wrote this code because I wondered "Should I push_back multiple single elements, or use insert?".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

vector<float> pushBackTest()
{
    vector<float> v;
    for(int i =0;i<10000000;i++)
    {
        // Using a for-loop took 200ms more (in the output)
        v.push_back(0);
        v.push_back(1);
        v.push_back(2);
        v.push_back(3);
        v.push_back(4);
        v.push_back(5);
        v.push_back(6);
        v.push_back(7);
        v.push_back(8);
        v.push_back(9);
    }
    return v;
}

vector<float> insertTest()
{
    vector<float> v;
    for(int i =0;i<10000000;i++)
    {
        v.insert(v.end(), {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9});
    }
    return v;
}

int main()
{
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point start = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    vector<float> a = pushBackTest();
    cout<<"pushBackTest: "<<chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(chrono::steady_clock::now() - start).count()<<"ms"<<endl;
    start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    vector<float> b = insertTest();
    cout<<"insertTest: "<<chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(chrono::steady_clock::now() - start).count()<<"ms"<<endl;
    assert(a==b);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
pushBackTest: 5544ms
insertTest: 3402ms
```

Since curiosity killed my time, I run a similar test but adding a single number instead of multiple ones.
So, the two new functions are:

```
vector<float> pushBackTest()
{
    vector<float> v;
    for(int i =0;i<10000000;i++)
    {

        v.push_back(1);

    }
    return v;
}

vector<float> insertTest()
{
    vector<float> v;
    for(int i =0;i<10000000;i++)
    {
        v.insert(v.end(), 1);
    }
    return v;
}
```

Output:

```
pushBackTest: 452ms
insertTest: 615ms
```

So, if you wanna add batch of elements, insert is faster, otherwise push_back it is. Also, keep in mind that push_back can only push... back, yeah.