# Why is std::inserter so slow?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, inserter

Let's consider the following code

```
#include <vector>
using container = std::vector<int>;
const int size  = 1000000;
const int count = 1000;
void foo(std::insert_iterator<container> ist)
{
    for(int i=0; i<size; ++i)
        *ist++ = i;
}
void bar(container& cnt)
{
    for(int i=0; i<size; ++i)
        cnt.push_back(i);
}
int main()
{
    container cnt;
    for (int i=0; i<count; ++i)
    {
        cnt.clear();
        #ifdef FOO
        foo(std::inserter(cnt, cnt.begin())); // using cnt.end() gives similar results
        #else
        bar(cnt);
        #endif
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I get huge performance variations

Using Foo:

```
$ g++ -g -pipe -march=native -pedantic -std=c++11 -W -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -o bin/inserter src/inserter.cc -DFOO
$ time ./bin/inserter
./bin/inserter  4,96s user 0,01s system 100% cpu 4,961 total
```

Using Bar:

```
$ g++ -g -pipe -march=native -pedantic -std=c++11 -W -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -o bin/inserter src/inserter.cc
$ time ./bin/inserter
./bin/inserter  2,08s user 0,01s system 99% cpu 2,092 total
```

Can someone explain why there are so much performance variation and why would someone want to use `std::inserter` ?

Answer (score 2):

Because you are inserting at the *front* of the vector rather than at the *back*. This causes frequent reallocations of the vector's storage. Insertions at the back on the other hand, will only require reallocations when the current capacity is exhausted (and which can be mitigated with the `cnt.reserve(N)` member).

Use a `std::back_inserter(cnt)` instead, which will call `cnt.push_back()` on each call to its dereference `operator*`.

See also [**this related**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13324431/819272) (but not quite duplicate IMO) Q&A for the differences between `insert` and `push_back`. The primary use of `std::inserter` is for insertions in the middle of a container, or for containers that lack a `push_back` member (or a `push_front` member, which would prevent the use of a `std::front_inserter`).

Comment: Using `foo(std::inserter(cnt, cnt.end()));` I get the same performance difference

Comment: Ok, now I've got a strange issue, editting or commenting `foo`'s code influences the performance when compiling without the -DFOO flag ...

Comment: @Amxx: `foo(std::inserter(cnt, cnt.end()));` inserts at the end, but only once. You have to use `std::back_inserter`.

Comment: @Jarod42: Eh, why does it?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Container is empty, so `end() == begin()`.

Comment: @Jarod42 `insert_iterator` after each assignment increments the position, so the comment "inserts at the end, but only once" is incorrect. `inserter(vec, vec.end())` is equivalent to `back_inserter(vec)`. The observed differences in speed are most likely due to implementation of `insert`, which is slower than `push_back` even at the end of the vector.

Comment: @WojtekSurowka No, `inserter(vec, vec.end())` is equivalent to `inserter(vec, vec.begin())`.

Comment: @Oktalist This is absolutely not true - the second argument is the position where new elements will be inserter. The two calls with end() and begin() are equivalent only if the vector is empty.

Comment: `inserter(vec, vec.end())` is equivalent to `inserter(vec, vec.begin() + vec.size())` (with fixed size).

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, and both are equivalent to `back_inserter(v)`, because after each assignment the position of `insert_iterator` is incremented. Also it is guaranteed that the position will not be invalidated by the insert operation executed by `insert_iterator`.

Comment: @Oktalist: Ehm, only on the first iteration, and at that time it is clearly entirely irrelevant to performance. Did you not spot that the call is made many times, in a loop?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit No, I (and Jarod) did not spot that `insert_iterator::operator=` increments `insert_iterator::iter`.