# push_back and insert which is faster in c++ stl?

Tags: c++, stl

Now in my program I have some data to store. I can store them in `std::map` or `std::vector`, either works. But I want to know which is faster `push_back in vector` or `insert in map`?

Comment: `vector` and `map` are quite different. What is the actual type you're storing? A `map` wont allow duplicates, and they both denote different things, so think first about readability.

Comment: There is already a question like this: Visit <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13324431/c-vectors-insert-push-back-difference>

Answer (score 0):

According to https://en.cppreference.com the complexity of `map::insert` is "Logarithmic in the size of the container" while `vector::push_back` is "Amortized constant".

This doesn't tell us which one is fastest when the container holds e.g. 10 elements but it does tell us that for large containers `vector::push_back` will be fastest.

Also notice that a vector allows you to reserve capacity up front.

Comment: "This doesn't tell us which one is fastest when the container holds e.g. 10 elements but it does tell us that for large containers vector::push_back will be fastest." - No, that's not what it does. In fact, it's a lot slower for large containers in the bad case. What it does say is that while a single push_back can be slow, repeated calls to push_back will average out to constant complexity.