# generated java files from MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I'm using MATLAB in order to write some algorithms, and after it I'm generating a C code files.
I'm considering to generate java files (instead of C files).

- Does someone has experience with it ?
- Is there any disadvantage when generating java files from MATLAB instead of C files ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a `matlab` utility to do what you are asking here: 
http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/javabuilder/ug/create-a-java-class-from-matlab-code.html

You will need the `Matlab Builder JA` package which will probably cost you money.

As for the advantages of Java vs c/c++, that question is way too opinionated to answer. I prefer c++ but it depends entirely on your application and personal preferences. There is some discussion about performance elements here:

[C++ performance vs. Java/C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145110/c-performance-vs-java-c)