# Why C++ is so much slower than Java in this Trie algorithm?

Tags: java, c++

I'm solving [problem336](https://leetcode.com/problems/palindrome-pairs/) in Leetcode, while I found the highest upvoted answer [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/palindrome-pairs/discuss/79195/O(n-*-k2)-java-solution-with-Trie-structure) used Trie structure in java. So, I wrote it in C++ again. I tried to optimize, but the Runtime and Memory are still very bad. Initially, I used shared_ptr, then the runtime: ~800 ms, memory: 400Mb. Then, I used new pointer, it became ~300ms, 200Mb. Still much slower than Java (20ms, 50Mb). I tried several times, but it's still 10x slower. My code structure and logic is just the same with the java implemented code, but it's so slow. I cannot figure out why!
here is my code:

```
struct TrieNode {
    TrieNode *next[26];
    int index = -1;
    vector<int> list;
    TrieNode(){
        memset(next,NULL,sizeof(next));
    }
    ~TrieNode() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 26; ++i) {
            if (next[i]) delete(next[i]);
        }
    }
};

bool isPalindrome(const string &word, int start, int end) {
    while (start < end) {
        if (word[start] != word[end])
            return false;
        ++start;
        --end;
    }
    return true;
}

int addword(TrieNode* root, const string &word, int index) {
    for (int i = word.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        int j = word[i] - 'a';
        if (!(root->next[j])) {
            root->next[j] = new TrieNode;
        }
        if (isPalindrome(word, 0, i))
            root->list.push_back(index);
        root = root->next[j];
    }
    root->index = index;
    root->list.push_back(index);
    return 0;
}

void search(TrieNode* root, vector<string> &words, int index, vector<vector<int>> &res) {
    for (int i = 0; i < words[index].size(); ++i) {
        if (root->index >= 0 && root->index != index && isPalindrome(words[index], i, words[index].size() - 1)) {
            res.push_back({index, root->index});
        }
        root = root->next[words[index][i] - 'a'];
        if (!root) return;
    }
    for (int i : root->list) {
        if (i == index) continue;
        res.push_back({index, i});
    }
}

vector<vector<int>> palindromePairs(vector<string>& words) {
    vector<vector<int>> res;
    TrieNode *root = new TrieNode;
    for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); ++i) {
        addword(root, words[i], i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); ++i) {
        search(root, words, i, res);
    }
    delete root;
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ performance vs. Java/C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145110/c-performance-vs-java-c)

Comment: Java calls `delete` never in such simple application.

Comment: How are you timing it? Taking leetcode’s timings? They’re very unreliable and have always been. Even running the same code several times can get wildly different results. So you’d need to set up a proper benchmark first.

Comment: There are tools called profilers that can help you understand where the time is going.

Comment: One possible suspect: `vector<int> list;`. From Java 8, `new ArrayList<>()` doesn't allocate the backing are - it is only allocated on the first `add()` call

Comment: Which compile command do you use, and does it contain -O3?

Comment: You don't need the `if` test in the destructor. `delete` already tests that. Don't test it again.