# Why string is sealed

Tags: c#, .net

I am curious why System.String is sealed?

I know, I can do whatever I need to do not inheriting it, but still -- why?

There are a lot of classes that, by nature, are strings having specific methods and properties. Those are identifiers, emails, names etc.

Object oriented design suggests to encapsulate functionality in a specific class. And here we have weird situation that the most usable fundamental type in the most popular object framework is not extendable.

Thank you.

EDITED.

Comment regarding immutability. It is easy to hide all state-related things in private methods and allow child classes to have read-only access to class's data.

```
// Safe inheritable immutable string (pseudocode).
class String
{
   // Private state
   private byte[] state;
   private void EditState(byte[]) {}
   // Protected read-only access to state
   protected byte getReadOnlyData() {}
   // Available to child classes overridable methods.
   protected virtual getHashCode() {}
   protected virtual xxx() {}
}
```

In fact most of objects in real-world applications are strings. All those serials, ASINs, IMEI etc, as well as names, comments, are string by their nature. We get them as strings from databases, or they typed as string somewhere in text boxes on a web page or canned by barcode scanners etc.

And it would be really nice, more secure and much more elegant to have strings with specific features instead of inventing multiple classes, more or less doing the same.

Comment: Worth reading [Why Are So Many Of The Framework Classes Sealed?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2004/01/22/why-are-so-many-of-the-framework-classes-sealed/)

Comment: The examples you’ve listed logically are *not* strings — though they can of course be implemented *in terms of* strings. But they should have difference interfaces, hence inheritance doesn’t make sense. This should really be the default stance (and, hence, classes should really be sealed by default, just as methods aren’t `virtual` by default in C#).

Comment: Your safe inheritance immutable string class actually should be composition of objects - string field and behavior over it Another words, it should be class with string property not a string inherited class.

Comment: If you are in need to inherit from sealed class why not use [extension methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb383977(v=vs.110).aspx) ?

Comment: Yes, I am able to do this as a composition, right, we all do it in that way, but but my point is why not inheritance. 

This is a fundamental feature of OOP and it is unavailable for the most popular class.

Comment: Anyway, thanks to @Steve, and his link to MSDN blogs article, we know answer -- this is too complex to MS to implement.

Comment: “why not inheritance” — because the consensus nowadays is that inheritance has many disadvantages (mainly tight coupling & interface bloat) compared to few advantages when compared to composition. This has changed since the early days of OOP, where people used it naïvely (due to lack of real world experience). One of the fundamental guidelines in modern OOP is therefore: [*composition over inheritance*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph, yes, right, composition is preferable over inheritance (especially when you build complex objects). But inheritance is not prohibited and .NET is, in fact, a huge hierarchy having one single root class. An sometimes it is much more handy.

Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> There are a lot of classes that, by nature, are strings having specific methods and properties. Those are identifiers, emails, names etc.

This specific use-case would be better-handled by composition rather than inheritance, that is: "an email address *has* a string-representation" instead of "an email address *is* a string" (because an email address is really a composite of multiple sub-fields that just happen to have a succinct string representation when you're using SMTP).

Another point is that String is meant to be a fundamental type - it doesn't make sense to derive from an `int` - why a string? You would only need to derive from `String` if you want to extend `System.String`'s implementation - for example, you want to override its `GetHashcode` implementation - but the number of operations you could conceivably want to override is very limited, so why should the framework maintainers bother with supporting that scenario?

As @Steve linked in the comments, this blog post by Eric Lippert also explains why many classes are `sealed`, especially from a maintenance PoV: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2004/01/22/why-are-so-many-of-the-framework-classes-sealed/

Finally, if you really want your own string behaviour (which is quite possible: you can length-prefixed strings, null-terminated strings, strings that exist as defined ranges in a larger string buffer, a linked-list based string, a Trie that holds multiple strings in a memory-efficient manner, a hybrid of multiple approaches, and so on) you can build your own implementation from scratch - none of these need to derive from `System.String` to exist. Sure, you wouldn't be able to pass it into a class that expects a String value, but that's only fair because perhaps those consumers depend on particular implementation behaviour of `System.String` (such as runtime performance, immutability, etc).

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

I know, inheritance is avoidable and so on. And email might be represented as a Email class having multiple fields. 

In fact, it's too heavy. 

Email is a string, and all I want to have is basic validation and some specific methods. And this is more secure and elegant end easy to implement than designing a completely new heavy class. 

This is what OOP is saying us to do -- reuse existing code.

Anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 7):

String is sealed mainly because it is immutable and CLR widely uses that feature (interning, cross-domain marshaling). If string would not be sealed then all CLR expectations on string immutability would not cost a dime.

Comment: Immutability is a good point, thank you.

Anyway, why immutable class can not be extended? Make all the internal state private and voila. 

And that would be some ChildString, not original System.String, so CLR won't be in trouble.

Comment: @DmitryKarpezo I think that's because 1. There is no point in inheritance when all base members are private. 2. Since we are talking about inheritance it should be applied when classes share common behavior. Now, when base class is immutable and another is not they are hardly common in nature.

Answer (score 4):

FYI 'implicit operators' are an alternative to extending sealed classes via inheritance. As long as new classes are only strongly typed strings. Those classes then become usable where string is expected... which simplifies usage

```
public class Email
{
    string m_stringfrom; // no other fields 

   public static implicit operator string(Email email)
   {
        return email.m_stringfrom;
    }
   public static implicit operator Email(string email)
   {
        return new Email() {
            m_stringfrom = email // only field in email !
        };
   }
}

void test()
{
    Email work_email = "test@domain.com";
    Display(work_email);
}
void Display( string toBeDisplayed)
{

}
```