# Why are some classes in the CLR sealed?

Tags: .net, vb.net, sealed

I've recently been using the `System.Version` [class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version(v=vs.110).aspx) and have wondered why it, and some other similarly simple enough classes, are marked as `Sealed` (`NotInheritable` in VB).

Unlike some more complex classes I don't see what such a class would gain by being sealed.

As far as I can tell the [source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/version.cs,0c15515dfe051d35) for `Version` does not imply any reason.

Is there a *published/official* (i.e. not opinion based) reason for this? Is there some problem that may be caused by deriving from it? Specifically for the case of `Version`, or failing that for similarly simple classes.

<sub>Background: I have had to recreate the `Version` class to make it easier to use it with two-way binding as the MS version has `ReadOnly` properties. But I'd need to know if deriving would cause some issue</sub>

Comment: Would that answer be enough http://stackoverflow.com/a/7777674/920557 ? see the [2] part

Comment: @EugeneKomisarenko Thanks, somewhat. Part 1 is obvious as to why an *application* programmer may seal a class (as opposed to a CLR programmer). Part 2 gives information that sounds logical but is based on heresay and doesn't make much sense considering that MS base classes are there to save us doing work, not force us to duplicate it. I'd prefer a more concrete source/reason if possible.

Comment: I believe in designing for inheritance or prohibiting it. Designing for inheritance takes some work and will usually limit implementations further along. With this in mind, classes should be either sealed or designed to be able to inherit them. What if you have an implementation from a base class that you have no control over? A sealed class prevents base class problems you have no control over and isnt intended to be inherited.

Comment: see: [Why Are So Many Of The Framework Classes Sealed?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2004/01/22/why-are-so-many-of-the-framework-classes-sealed/)

Comment: For future reference, the Ingo Rammer article mentioned in the comments of the page linked to by @TnTinMn is available in the internet archive here http://web.archive.org/web/20061110133859/http://www.thinktecture.com/Resources/Articles/SealedIsGood.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Version` is a class representing a “value”, similar to `DateTime`, but being too large to comfortably fit into a `struct`, it's `class`. The same design principles apply, though. Types representing values should be immutable and sealed (value types are always sealed).

You can also clearly see other hallmarks of values:

- `object.Equals` and `object.GetHashCode` have been overridden.
- It implements `IEquatable<Version>`

Comment: Is there a rule, or rule of thumb on when a struct is "too large"? Coming from a C background I *generally* like to keep my structs solely for fields; if they need functionality then that's a class.

Comment: @Toby, for general guidelines, see: [Choosing Between Class and Struct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: For my future reference, in this specific situation my "BetterVersion" class should probably actually *wrap* the CLR `Version` class rather than inheriting from it ("is-a" relationship), composing from it ("has-a" relationship) or reproducing it.