# In which cases should I use a seal class?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why seal a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268251/why-seal-a-class)

I haven't seen a lot of classes with this modifier, however I'm wondering in which kind of scenarios this would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

In case you do not wand anyone to extend a class.

Classic example is a String class, it's self-sufficient and implements flyweight pattern, that might be easily destroyed if anyone could overwrite it's methods/properties.

You want to use the sealed class if you provide your API that doesn't need to be changed, for any of above reasons.