# What care need to take inheriting from library class?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

We have application in Java, and we are using one library class. After long time after project start we got situation where, in every function we have used that class we want to add one more element in object of the class (just adding value, not adding any new member).

This change is huge. Not difficult to do, but we have used this class in 100s of functions.

Now one solution is we can inherit this class and add required change in derived class. We keep name of class same (and use fully qualified name for base class to inherit), just will change package name so we can use derived class in our code.

Is there any problem in this approach? Because my manager's suggestion is 'Its not easy as it seems to be'.

Kindly suggest if I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: Creating a subclass of a library class and using it in your methods seems fine. You may go ahead with this approach.

Comment: Its OOP. So it wont be a problem unless if it is not permitted by your admins.

Comment: I mean your superiors. You said about your manager. Your approach seems legitimate. Actually it is OOP. So why not.

Comment: @Sudhanshu Thanks. This could be answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether inheritance is the best solution depends upon the element you are trying to add. If possible consider composition over inheritance. The advantages can be found [here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2013/06/why-favor-composition-over-inheritance-java-oops-design.html). There you can find a example of one of the pitfall when one tries to override one of the methods. This is more possible in your case since you do not have the source code of library.

Answer (score 0):

you can make small changes in the original class as long as it does not interfere with the original functioning of the class. this is better idea instead of making a derived class with the same name as base class.

Comment: Original class is from library. We do not have it's source code.

Comment: in that case derive the class but use different name , i am assuming you are using eclipse therefore use the refractor to change the name of the class in all of the code.

Answer (score 0):

If all you're adding is a single variable, this is *probably* safe. Anything more complicated [is dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588158/why-there-is-an-option-for-a-class-in-oop-be-marked-to-never-inherit-from-ancest/21116956). I don't have any code to go on, but inheritance is probably not the right choice. What happens if you make another subclass that adds a different field, and a few months later you realize now you need both fields? Inheritance is not composable - you can't mix and match the specializations you make in subclasses. Use aggregation. If you need a Foo that also has a Bar, then make a simple container class that has both a foo and a bar:

```
class FooWithBar {
    public final Foo foo;
    public final Bar bar;

    public FooWithBar(Foo foo, Bar bar) {
        this.foo = foo;
        this.bar = bar;
    }
}
```