# Operator Overloading in Clojure

Tags: functional-programming, clojure, operator-overloading

Even looking closely over documentation on Clojure, I do not see any *direct* confirmation as to whether or not Clojure supports operator overloading.

If it does, could someone provide me with a quick snipplet of how to overload, let's say, the "+" operator to delegate to some predefined method that we can call `myPlus`.

I am *very* new to Clojure, so someone's help here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Clojure's (as any Lisp's) operators are plain functions; you can define an "operator" like a function:

```
(defn ** [x y] (Math/pow x y))
```

The "+" operator (and some other math-operators) is a special case in Clojure, since it is inlined (for the binary case, at least). You can to a certain extent avoid this by not referring to `clojure.core` (or excluding `clojure.core/+`) in your namespace, but this can be very hairy.

To create a namespace where + is redefined:

```
(ns my-ns
  (:refer-clojure :exclude [+]))

(defn + [x y] (println x y))

(+ "look" "ma")
```

One good strategy would probably be to make your + a multimethod and call core's + function for the numeric cases.

Comment: So, if I were to exclude clojure.core/+, I could do the following (defn + [x y] (myPlus x y)) correct?  If so, that is exactly what I want to do.  How do I exclude clojure.core/+ from my namespace?

Comment: I've added this to my answer.

Comment: Actually, after trying this: it doesn't seem to work.  I try it and get the following error: java.lang.Exception: Name conflict, can't def + because namespace: my-ns refers to:#'clojure.core/+ (NO_SOURCE_FILE:5)

Comment: Please enable public editing so I can fix my vote on your answer (and give you a well-deserved +1)

Comment: I don't actually know how to do this.

Comment: Make some arbitrary changes to your answer, and I should be able to fix my voting mistake.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at this:
http://clojure.org/multimethods

Certain functions, like + are core and cannot be redefined.

You could make a new function and call it ".+" or "!+" for example, which is similar in terms of readability.

Using the information in the multimethods URL included above, you can build a function that tells your .+ which implementation to use.

Comment: You didn't answer his question one way or the other.

Comment: `+` can be easily redefined in a different namespace. In fact you can even redefine `+` in clojure.core if you like (though not recommended....)