# operator << overloading - C++ vs Java

Tags: java, operator-overloading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Operator overloading in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686699/operator-overloading-in-java)

I have a small question.
If operator << used for `cout` purpose in C++ is overloaded,
can we do the same in Java? And if we can, what will it correspond to?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing to cout << overloading in Java is the ToString method that every class can replace.

Comment: not exactly. `<<` is a stream operator when used in the context of `cout`.

Comment: Even if it's not an exact equivalent, it is still a fair bid for the _closest thing_ to customizing how a particular type is printed to a stream.

Comment: @daniel It is not exactly the same, but it is the closet thing I can think of and that is what the OP is asking for, what in Java is most like cout << in Java.  (I can't type backquote on my phone)

Comment: I see what Daniel is saying in that they're completely different. But I also see Iron's perspective in that they're both the "go to approach to display".

Answer (score 5):

Java doesn't have operator overloading.

Answer (score 1):

There is no operator overloading in Java.