# Change what happens when = operator is invoked upon a class java

Tags: java, class, equals

I have a class, shown below, which needs to be able to use equals in the way int does, for example: you don't say

```
int i = new Integer(1);
```

you say

```
int i = 1;
```

how do i define what happens when = is invoked on a class?

**And what is the difference between**

```
    int i1 = new Integer(5);
```

and

```
    Integer i2 = new Integer(5);
```

Comment: NO operator overloading in java.  
check
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686699/operator-overloading-in-java

Comment: `=` is *never* "invoked on a class/value". Ever. It assigns a value (sometimes a "reference to an object") to a variable (or member variable). That's it. Look, no class involved: `int i = 1;` or `String s = null;` In this case, look up "auto boxing".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't, it is only defined in the language and you can't change it. Btw, what you're mentioning is called **["autoboxing"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html)** and only happens for primitive times since Java 1.5