# How to use operations like +-*/ on java-objects

Tags: java, class, methods, wrapper, fractions

I need to program a java-class "Fraction".

This class should be able to understand the basic arithmetic operations like +, -, *, /. I found lots of "Fraction" classes and understand them, but all use methods like "**f1.add(f2);**" (f1, f2 are objects of Fraction, for Example:

```
f1 = new Fraction(1,5);
f2 = new Fraction(2,5);
```

What I need is a direct manipulation like the manipulation of integers, for example:

```
**f1 = f1 + f2;**
```

instead of

```
f1.add(f2);
```

Comment: Why do you *need* it?  The methods do the same thing and work fine.

Answer (score 6):

You can't: java doesn't allow overloading operators.

Comment: Thanks for that answer. So I will have to try out a new programming language :/
Someone has an advice for me? C#, C++? Perhaps PHP?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in standard Java.

As you have asked explicitly in a comment: I suggest *Scala* (in contrast to *Groovy*), because it's type-safe (among many other advantages), and it is a JVM language as well:

```
class Fraction(val n: Int, val d: Int) {
  override def toString = s"$n/$d"

  def +(that: Fraction) = new Fraction(this.n + that.n, this.d)
}

object FractionDemo extends App {
  val f1 = new Fraction(1, 4)
  val f2 = new Fraction(2, 4)
  val f3 = f1 + f2
  println(s"$f1 + $f2 = $f3")
}
```

and the output is

> 1/4 + 2/4 = 3/4

I know that `+` is not implemented correctly, this is just a small example.

If you are interested in a numerical library for *Scala*, have a look at [spire](https://github.com/non/spire), it already has a `Fractional` class.

Answer (score 0):

As eternay said, Java doesn't support operator overloading. You could look at [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/).It is a Java-like JVM-based language which does support operator overloading.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in a language based in JVM that support operator overloading you can try Groovy.
See here some discussion:
[Operator overloading in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686699/operator-overloading-in-java)