# How do I define what an operator does for a class in Java

Tags: java, vector, addition

I've created a Vector class and want to add be able to add the Vector's X and Y by just doing

```
Vector a + Vector b
```

Is it possible to do this in Java?

Comment: Sure.  Create a method  `Vector.add(Vector)`..

Comment: Specifically, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1686740/1204134).

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but you cannot define or overload operators in Java. Implement an `add` method. You can have the `add` method return `this`, to allow chaining of operations (e.g., `sum = a.add(b).add(c)`), but that does not always result in the most readable code.