# Can you implement a method to act as a +... but for objects instead of primitives?

Tags: java, addition, primitive

I think that there is something like this in C/C++, but what about in java? Can I add a method that will add two of them together, but instead of doing say `obj1.add(obj2)` you can do `obj1 + obj2`? Can you do the same for -, *, /, and == & other comparatives? Can you create a primitive, or would that take modifying the JVM?

Comment: no, you can't do that in java

Answer (score 1):

That's called `operator overloading`. And no Java does not support it. You can find more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686699/operator-overloading-in-java).

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot. There is no operator overloading in Java. The only thing that comes close to an overloaded operator in Java is + which can concatenate strings and perform standard addition.