# Add two generic types into another type

Tags: java, generics, generic-programming

In my code i have (E and V are generic types):

```
E info;
V v1, v1;
```

If i write:

```
info = (E) v1 + v2
```

I get an error: SparseGraph.java:163: operator + cannot be applied to V,V.

How can i add v1 and v2 to get the result inside the "info" variable? As you can see i'm using this code to create a SparseGraph and info is the information of an Edge of the graph. IF the edge affect vertex "A" and vertex "B", info should be "AB".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to define an `Add` operation for you to be able to do that. This is because the concept of adding differs as you use different types. For instance, `5` + `9` yields `14` if you treat them as integers, but you get `59` if you treat them as strings (assuming you are using the default implementation of `+` for string).

So in shorts, your `V` must implement a method called `add` (since Java does not support [operator overloading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_overloading), as pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686699/operator-overloading-in-java)) which takes one or more other `V` type objects. In this method, you would have the logic you are describing.

```
public V add(V source)
{
    //logic to add sparse graphs.
}
```

Also, this line: `info = (E) v1 + v2` assumes that `V` can be casted to `E` in some way. You might also need to implement a method in `V` which given a sparse graph, you can get your edges.

As per your question:

> Also doing info = (E) v1.toString() + v2.toString() is wrong?

In your case it is. In this case, what you are doing is that you are concatenating the string representations of `v1` and `v2` respectively. Assuming you did *override* such methods within your `V` class so that you can print something you can work with, the `+` operator for strings does not have the logic you need. Also, you would then need to cast the string into an object of type `E`, which is most likely to fail.

Comment: Also doing info = (E) v1.toString() + v2.toString() is wrong?

Comment: @MarcoMicheli: I have modified my response to answer your question. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can not overload operators. That is you can not directly sum two objects using the `+` operator. Instead, you need to implement an `add(Object)` method for instance.