# Java: add two objects

Tags: java, object

I was making a project in [Greenfoot](http://www.greenfoot.org/door) and I made an imaginary number class. In my project I found a need to add (or subtract, or whatever) two imaginary objects together, is there a way to add two objects like that? So this is how it would look in a perfect world:

```
    Imaginary i1 = new Imaginary(1.7,3.14);
    Imaginary i2 = new Imaginary(5.3,9.1);
    //the class Imaginary has parameters (double real, double imaginary)
    Imaginary i3 = i1+i2;
```

Is that possible?

Comment: However, in Java there is no such thing as operator overloading. It would have to be written similar to `i3 = i1.add(i2)` (where `add` is a method that does the appropriate logic and creates the new object).

Comment: This is a very valid question, I don't understand the downvotes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java has **no operator overloading**.

For example, `BigDecimal` would be a lot more popular if you could write `a + b` instead of `a.add(b)`.

**Way 1**.

```
Imaginary i3 = i1.add(i2);
```

Method:

```
public static Imaginary add(Imaginary i2)
{
    return new Imaginary(real + i2.real, imaginary + i2.imaginary);
}
```

**Way 2**.

```
Imaginary i3 = add(i1, i2)
```

Method:

```
public static Imaginary add(Imaginary i1, Imaginary i2)
{
    return new Imaginary(i1.real + i2.real, i1.imaginary + i2.imaginary);
}
```

Operator overloading would have definitely made design more complex than without it, and it might have led to more complex compiler or slows the JVM.

Comment: Java actually _does_ have operator overloading (eg the `+` operator for the String class), so it's obvious that compiler design/performance didn't enter into it. If memory serves, the developers chose to disallow operator overloading for _user-designed_ _classes_ because they felt that it reduced program readability and clarity.

Answer (score 9):

What you are describing is called "Operator overloading" and it cannot be accomplished in Java (at least by programmers such as you and me; the developers have free reign to do this and did so with the String class). Instead, you can create an `add` method and call that:

```
Imaginary i3 = i1.add(i2);
```

Answer (score 6):

Try Like this.

```
Imaginary i3 =new Imaginary(i1.real+i2.real,i1.imaginary+i2.imaginary);
```

If you want to add `Object` you can create method for addition.

```
public static Imaginary add(Imaginary i1,Imaginary i2)
{
return new Imaginary(i1.real+i2.real,i1.imaginary+i2.imaginary);
}
```

And create Object from this

```
Imaginary i3 =add(i1,i2);
```

Answer (score 4):

It is possible in C++, but not in Java, define a function `addImaginary(Imaginary, Imaginary)` which will add two Imaginarys and store them in the object will called the method.

It will look like:

```
i3.addImaginary(i1, i2)
```

But it is up to you how you define the function, it can also be done as:

```
i3=i1.add(i2);
```

Answer (score 4):

[Java doesn't support user-defined operator overloading.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1686708/2670792) But you can make a method in your `Imaginary` class:

```
public static Imaginary add(Imaginary other) {
    return new Imaginary(real + other.real, imaginary + other.imaginary);
}
```

so, you can call it like:

```
Imaginary i3 = i1.add(i2);
```