# Multiplying an object by an integer in java?

Tags: java, object

I've got a simple class called Vector2 which is pretty much:

```
class Vector2 {
    public int x, y;
    public Vector2(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

With some methods, etc. I'd like to be able to do:

```
Vector2 myVector = new Vector2(2, 1);
myVector *= 2;
```

and myVector would be (4, 2).

Is this possible? What would I need to add to my class?

Comment: Java does not allow user-defined operator overloading, so I don't think you can do this.

Comment: Thanks, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23178398/java-add-two-objects) answered my question.

Answer (score 4):

```
Vector2 myVector = new Vector2(2, 1);
myVector *= 2;
```

> Is this possible?

No. Not in Java. Other languages like C++ support that. Called Operator overloading because you redefine what the `*`-operator does.

In Java you have to use explicit methods. Like

```
myVector.multiplyBy( 2 )
```

and it would look like

```
class Vector2 {
    public int x, y;
    public Vector2(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public void multiplyBy(int value) {
        this.x *= value;
        this.y *= value;
    }
}
```

or like

```
    public Vector2 multiplyBy(int value) {
        return new Vector2(this.x * value, this.y * value);
    }
```

And then you would do

```
Vector2 myMultipliedVector = myVector.multiplyBy( 2 );
```

with the advantage that you don't modify the original object but create a new one with a different value.

---

[Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/operators.html#Operator-Overloading) (language that is derived from Java & runs on the JVM) takes that idea and actually allows you to write  `someObject *= 2` as long as you provide a method that must be called `multiply`. Maybe one day that makes it into Java. [Maybe not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77718/why-doesnt-java-offer-operator-overloading). But basically all legal Java code is also legal Groovy code so you could do it right now, in a program that looks like Java and runs in the Java VM.

Comment: Thanks, in that case I'd rather just do the `new Vector2(x * 2, y * 2)`.