# Operator definition in java

Tags: java, operator-overloading, operators

```
int i = 10;
i++; // it ok primitive value can use ++.

Integer integer = 10;
integer++; // how it can use ++

MyClass myClass  = new MyClass();
myClass++; // then why myclass can't use ++.
```

Comment: `integer++;` works because of autoboxing (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)

Comment: It says that int get converted in Integer at compile time.
So i write a Test code:
class Demo{ int i = 10; } 
then compiled and obtain Demo.class.

when i open Demo.class with decompiler "int i" is still there.

Comment: Are you looking for an answer helping you to allow the `myClass++;` statement? Or just explaining why `integer++;` works?

Comment: I am looking answer for both why and how integer++ work. and how i can make myclass++ work.(although i know operator overloading is not allowed in java)

Answer (score 4):

C++ has the ability to *overload operators*. The Java language considers this to be open to too much abuse (overloaded operators can be obfuscating) so it was never incorporated into Java.

Therefore, you can't write `myClass++` as the syntax is not available to specify that operation.

But `++` does work on a selection of non-primitives. The mechanism exploited is called *autoboxing*. (Essentially the underlying plain-old-data type is extracted from the boxed type, incremented then re-boxed to the original reference type).

Somewhat related to this is the ability to apply `+=` and `+` to `java.lang.String` instances. Simply put, this is a special case. Although fully aware of the risk of downvotes I regard this as one of the worst kludges in Java, particularly `+=` which will create a new instance of a string (as strings themselves are immutable), and many Java programmers will be unaware of the effect this has on memory.

Comment: Ok. But there should be something special(that my class can't do) where Integer can. I am looking for that special thing. (Not to implement just to check)

Comment: That special thing is *autoboxing*. Have a google on it. I summarise it in parentheses but more detail can be found in reference texts.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) provided in a comment by Konstantin V. Salikhov,

`Integer` has a defined method to return an `int`, which then has the `++` operator defined.
`MyClass` has no `++` operator, hence `myClass++;` is invalid

The method in question goes like:

```
Integer myInteger = 10;
myInteger.intValue++;
```

Autoboxing is the automatic conversion that the Java compiler makes between the primitive types and their corresponding object wrapper classes.

Operator overloading in Java has a description (as to it being not allowed) at [Operator overloading in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686699/operator-overloading-in-java)

Comment: Please improve your answer.you are right but explanation is needed.

Comment: I can a class like:

class MyClass{

int i;

public int getInt(){
return i;
}

}

then ++ will work??

Comment: @DeepanshuBedi Thanks for adding the link via edit, I'm not sure what happened but I guess someone with review priveledges changed it already.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of Java's autoboxing feature which is added in Java 1.5
The compiler will convert the statment as follow

```
Integer integer = 10;
integer.iniValue++;
```

You can try to add the compiler flag "javac -source 1.4" and it will return an error