# Java - custom array getter

Tags: java, arrays, getter

Does Java have any possibility of c# equal syntax

```
class MyClass{
    private int[] array = new int[20];
    public int this[int index] { get{ return array[i];}} //<-- array getter for object
}

MyClass test = new MyClass();
Console.WriteLine(test[0]);
```

( Code is just example ;) )

Comment: Write a class that wraps the array and does whatever you want.

Comment: read this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686699/operator-overloading-in-java

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Java does not support operator overloading, including the array subscript (`[]`) operator.

Answer (score 5):

No, you cannot override/overload operators - Java doesn't support that. However, you can add a get method like:

```
class MyClass{
    private int[] array = new int[20];
    public int get(int i) { return array[i]; }
}
```