# How to create a Class, in which we can assign value directly

Tags: java, class, classloader

May be the title will misguide you.

```
String str ="abcd";
```

In the above code String is a class and without using new we can create an object with value. Now I have a class Number.java in which I have to assign some number as shown below.

```
Number no = 23;
```

How to create such class.

Comment: Think, how will you tell the compiler that what kind of object you are assigning to the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would normally say that you should be using Operator Overloading. But this feature does not exist in Java.

See here: [Operator overloading in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686699/operator-overloading-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly assign value to Object like Strings.

If you really want to achieve the same thing, I would suggest you to create a Factory of pre-defined initialized objects and get the required object from Factory by using [`Prototype`](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/01/04/prototype-design-pattern-in-java/) pattern or [`FactoryMethod`](http://howtodoinjava.com/2012/10/23/implementing-factory-design-pattern-in-java/) pattern.

Sample code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.*;

public class PrototypeFactory
{
    public class NumberPrototype
    {
        public static final String THIRTY_TWO = "32";
        public static final String FORTY_ONE = "41";

    }

    private static java.util.Map<String , AtomicInteger> prototypes = new java.util.HashMap<String , AtomicInteger>();

    static
    {
        prototypes.put(NumberPrototype.THIRTY_TWO, new AtomicInteger(32));
        prototypes.put(NumberPrototype.FORTY_ONE, new AtomicInteger(43));

    }

    public static AtomicInteger getInstance( final String s) {
        //return (AtomicInteger)(prototypes.get(s)).clone();
        return ((AtomicInteger)prototypes.get(s));
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println("Prototype.get(32):"+PrototypeFactory.getInstance(NumberPrototype.THIRTY_TWO));
    }
}
```

output:

```
Prototype.get(32):32
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

The Java compiler is just providing you with a syntactical shortcut.

From the [Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html):

> [...] a string literal [is] a series of characters in your code that
>   is enclosed in double quotes. Whenever it encounters a string literal
>   in your code, the compiler creates a String object with its value

Answer (score 0):

Actually this type of assignment does work for the primitive wrapper classes due to auto-boxing

```
Integer n = 23;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't since the primitive values are part of the java language, if you wanted to make a class to be "initialized" like that you should add it to the java parse or something like that.