# How can I add 2 objects in java

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and I couldn't find an answer to it anywhere because i don't even know how to search for it.

I want to define how 2 objects can be added together, so you get a new one like for example you can add String "a" and String "b" to get "ab".

I know this can be done in python by doing `self.__add__(self, other)`.
How can you do this in Java?

Comment: In case of strings you can just use +: `"a" + "b"`. For all other objects (except wrapper classes for primitive number types) you need to provide a method in the class. As an example, have a look at `BigDecimal`.

Comment: No, Java doesn't support user-defined operator overloading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686699/operator-overloading-in-java

Comment: Do you want to concatenate Strings? Then you can use the `+` operator. If you want to overload `+`, that's not possible. Otherwise you can just create a method (maybe call it `add`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing you are looking for is called operator overloading. It exists in some languages, however in Java it does not.

The best thing you can do is to define a method add() inside the class and then use it like this:

```
object1.add(object2);
```

I know it looks nicer with a + between them, but that would make compiling more complex.

Comment: We should note that built-in operator overloading does exist in Java, what doesn't exist is the user-defined variety.

Answer (score 1):

With the exception of `java.lang.String` being treated as a special case<sup>1</sup>, Java does not allow you to *define* the behaviour of `+` for arbitrary types, or indeed any other operator, as you can in some languages such as C++ or Scala. In other words, Java does not support *operator overloading*.

Your best bet is to build functions like `add` &c. Appeal to precedent here: see how the Java guys have done it with `BigInteger`, for example. Sadly there is no way of defining the *precedence* of your functions, so you have to use very many parentheses to tell the compiler how you want an expression to be evaluated. It's for this reason that I don't use Java for any serious mathematical applications as the implementation of even a simple equation quickly becomes an unreadable mess<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> Which in some ways does more harm than good: e.g. consider `1 + 2 + "Hello" + 3 + 4`. This compile time constant expression is a string type with the value `3Hello34`.

<sup>2</sup> Note that C++ was used to model the gravitational lensing effects of the wormhole in the movie "Interstellar". I challenge anyone to do that in a language that does not support operator overloading! See https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.03808v1.pdf

Comment: Why can't I upvote your answer? It says I need 15 reputation, but how can i get that?

Comment: Earn it by asking good questions (such as this one: I will upvote it), writing good answers and making good edit suggestions. The 15 rep threshold guards us against trolls. (Good answers are normally upvoted eventually).

Comment: Thanks for the upvote, but since i am a beginner i cannot really answer many questions out there and definitely not better like someone like you.

Comment: I think it is on the whole. Trolls distorting the voting process could discredit it - it does take a surprisingly large amount of effort to earn +15 on this site! As a beginner you can still ask good questions, and make good edit suggestions.

Comment: `I challenge anyone to do that in a language that does not support operator overloading!` As so often happens in software development, it's horses for courses.

Answer (score 0):

Java does not allow you to override operators.  `String` is a special case that does allow this functionality.

What you can do is add an `add` function like so:

```
public YourObject add(YourObject yourObject){
    return new YourObject(this.propertyToAdd + yourObject.propertyToAdd);
}
```